# August Movie Event #2!

Tags: discussion, movie-night

Our most recent chat event ([The Day the Earth Stood Still](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/conversation/the-day-the-earth-stood-still)) was our most successful yet, with five commenters and 13 another lurkers watching from the sidelines.

**It's now time to pick August's Movie Event #2!!! (woo!!!)**

---

## Update - As the answer with the joint highest overall score and highest number of upvotes, our choice for the next event is (...[drumroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itAOGRiYRLI)....) **Alien**!

Join us in the chatroom on 22nd August at 10pm UTC to watch together

<s>As before, you need to pick your preferred film and post it as an answer below. Upvote the ones you like and the top answer (by Thursday 20th August at midnight UTC) will be selected as the winner. We'll then watch together on Saturday 22nd August at 10pm UTC in the [Mos Eisley chatroom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72PMQ.jpg).</s>

Choose wisely and remember, <s>all</s> most suggestions will be considered carefully, with <s>no exceptions</s> [very few exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signs_(film))

[image]

Comment: I notice that nothing in this post mentions scifi as opposed to fantasy. Nomination coming up!

Comment: @randal'thor - Too late, mi amigo.

Comment: Never too late for a rollback! ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Curses. I forgot to lock it.

Comment: Aw man... I wasn't checking the site and missed this. I hope you guys had a good time.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Our best yet. 10 commenters and 15+ lurkers... :-)

Comment: @Richard - Neat.  Time for a new contest!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the classic movie *Alien*.  'Nuff said.

[image]

Comment: I've got to wait the whole movie to see that damn thing screetch out of his stomach, yich!

Comment: @jmfb - Shh! Spoilers!

Comment: @Richard has anybody on this site not seen Alien? My lips are sealed, lol.

Comment: "There's a horror movie called Alien? That's really offensive. No wonder everyone keeps invading you." - 12th Doctor Who

Answer (score 3):

Minority Report. Mainly because I've been meaning to rewatch it for ages.

Answer (score 3):

[Stardust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(2007_film)), one of the best films I've ever seen.

[image: poster]

It ticks ALL the boxes. Whatever you want, Stardust has it.

- Romance: an emotional and convincing love story at the heart (pun intended!) of the plot
- Action: plenty of swordfighting, daring escapes, and galloping horseback chases
- Intrigue: power-hungry princes plotting to assassinate one another to gain the throne
- Cast: Robert de Niro as a flying pirate with a fascinating character, Michelle Pfeiffer, Claire Danes, that inimitable villain of villains Mark Strong, Peter O'Toole and Ricky Gervais in minor roles
- Soundtrack: [fantastic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JQSeTKOr-Q)
- Dialogue: witty, moving, tons of quotes you'll want to remember

Suspense is kept up very well throughout, character development is a central theme, and the ending is even better than in the book!

Frankly, anyone who doesn't like this film can sod off :-D

Comment: There are *some* sci-fi elements, notably the flying ship.

Comment: +1 I've never seen this movie, it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Since it did fairly well in the prior poll, I'm going to renominate *[Hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_(film))*. If I keep proposing it, it will eventually be the right answer. ^_^

[image]

Comment: I upvoted (again).

Answer (score 2):

Time Bandits! Monty Python's own Terry Gilliam as director, and George Harrison soundtrack to boot!

[image]

Comment: A fine choice :-)

Comment: @Richard I thought you'd like this choice. What a great flick. Finally you gave me an upvote? What's the date and time? LOL

Comment: Read the main post for the times. :-)

Comment: +1 for George Harrison.

Comment: @Richard I meant the time and date for the first upvote I've received from you, lol.

Comment: @Richard somebody downvoted time bandits?!?

Comment: @JMFB - There's no accounting for (bad) taste  :-)

Answer (score 1):

[*Things to Come*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn76zoYjr4k)

[image]

Comment: What's good about it?

Comment: @Richard No light sabers, no transporter beams, no flying broomsticks, no dwarf tossing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest the 1984 classic "The Terminator".

What's not to like? Gunplay, time-traveling robot<s>s</s>, Linda Hamilton's enormous hair...

[image]

As an added bonus, we can all hoot and holler during the highly erotic [sex scene](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A8z3mQUCEAAAVa2.jpg)

Comment: The 80's FTW...

Answer (score 0):

I may actually be able to attend this one! As such, I would like to nominate;

[*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDcQFjACahUKEwiky_jEpbLHAhWMWNsKHSNzArc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt1843866%2F&ei=ePfSVaSvLYyx7Qaj5om4Cw&usg=AFQjCNG5o7XKZZ6xH_dNJCN5BMENDJ6c4A&bvm=bv.99804247,d.ZGU), which is the 9th film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, the 6th live action Captain America film, the 2nd Captain America film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, the 3rd film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe to have Captain America in it and the 7th live action film which contains Captain America.

Directed by the Russo Brothers (most well known for their directing work on *Community*), *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* follows Steve Rogers, who after the events of *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* finds himself working for SHIELD. After SHIELD director Nick Fury is attacked by the mysterious Winter Soldier, Steve teams up with Sam Wilson and Natasha Romanoff in order to find out what exactly is going on.