# September Chatroom Movie event #1

Tags: discussion, movie-night

UPDATE: Stardust was our winner!

---

Our most recent chat movie event, the classic 1979 film "[Alien](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/august-movie-event-2)" proved ridiculously popular, with no less than 10 active commenters and nearly 20 lurkers watching from the sidelines.

**It's now time to pick September's first chatroom Movie Event! *(can I get a woop-woop!?)***

---

As before, you need to **pick your preferred film and post it as an answer below**. Upvote the ones you like and the top answer (by Saturday 12th September at midnight UTC) will be selected as the winner. We'll then watch together on Sunday 13th September at 10pm UTC in the [Mos Eisley chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

Choose wisely and remember, <s>all</s> most suggestions will be considered carefully, with <s>no exceptions</s> very few exceptions

[image]

Comment: [Here's your Whoop Whoop!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt7hoHBcY9k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Re-nominated; it was equal highest-voted answer last time)

[**Stardust**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(2007_film)), one of the best films I've ever seen.

[image: poster]

It ticks ALL the boxes. Whatever you want, Stardust has it.

- Romance: an emotional and convincing love story at the heart (pun intended!) of the plot
- Action: plenty of swordfighting, daring escapes, and galloping horseback chases
- Intrigue: power-hungry princes plotting to assassinate one another to gain the throne
- Cast: Robert de Niro as a flying pirate with a fascinating character, Michelle Pfeiffer, Claire Danes, that inimitable villain of villains Mark Strong, Peter O'Toole and Ricky Gervais in minor roles
- Soundtrack: [fantastic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JQSeTKOr-Q)
- Dialogue: witty, moving, tons of quotes you'll want to remember

Suspense is kept up very well throughout, character development is a central theme, and the ending is even better than in the book!

Frankly, anyone who doesn't like this film can sod off :-D

Comment: You have my +1 (again).

Comment: Here's me sodding off. ;)

Comment: Is it available via Hulu, Netflix, or Amazon Prime Instant?

Comment: @JackBNimble You may (or may not) be able to view it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEsRSOwsUtQ). (I had a better Youtube link, but can't seem to find it again...)

Comment: @JackBNimble - The important thing is not to watch it on putlocker. Because that would be wrong, WRONG, WRONG!

Answer (score 4):

What about Westworld?

[image]

It's a classic sci-fi movie with an intriguing plot. With the TV reboot coming soon, it will help everyone get up to date with the original.

It also has a lot of stupid things and parts that don't make sense, so everyone can make fun of it.

Comment: I saw the sequel to this without even knowing it was a sequel. It used some laughable, though likely some of the earliest, computer animation. I'm also pretty sure there was a nude Peter Fonda scene, well, robot version of Peter Fonda. I heard the original was better, like a westerny Terminator (evil Schwarzenegger one), and I never got a chance to see it.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero Yes, the original had the first use of CGI in a film. It was used to give one of the robots futuristic-looking vision. It ended up looking more like a really old video game.

Answer (score 1):

[Logan's Run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film)) (1976, [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/))

[image]

Comment: Great film. Another +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to nominate [Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/), James Camerons's magnum opus. Quite literally the finest sci-fi film ever made and acknowledged to be one of the single greatest films of all time.

Anyone voting for other films should hang their heads in shame.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

As a break from my record of suggesting classics, I nominate the independent Irish sci-fi/horror/comedy film *Grabbers*.

[image: Poster]

> Rotten Tomatoes, a review aggregator, reports that Grabbers received positive reviews from 72% of 29 surveyed critics; the average rating was 6.3/10. Damon Wise of Empire film magazine described it as "a romantic but surprisingly scary monster movie that feels like a lost Amblin flick, shaken and stirred with a dash of The Guard. ... a finely crafted tribute to a long-lost style of filmmaking [that] stands up in its own right too." Matt Glasby of Total Film rated it 3/5 stars and called it "a bright, breezy Irish monster mash boasting gorgeous cinematography, appealing performances and great SFX". Gareth Jones of DreadCentral rated it 4/5 stars and said, "it is one hell of a good time that offers plenty of laughs, excellent characters and performances, and big slimy monsters." Jordan Hoffman of US cable channel IFC summed the film up as "a delightful romp", while Upcoming Movies gave it four stars and called it a "fun, monster movie roller coaster" with a "mix of laughs and scares". The Daily Telegraph‍ '​s Robbie Collin called it a "cherishable Irish B-picture ... with an unimprovable premise".  Kim Newman of Screen Daily said of the film: "Kevin Lehane's smart script is canny enough to sidestep the expectations of fans who might think they know how films like this are supposed to play out, while the monsters are as well-realised as anything in far more costly productions."  The Irish Times said, "Grabbers has an atmosphere all its own: the humour is earthy without being patronising; the action sequences are both absurd and properly exciting." Peter Bradshaw of The Guardian rated the film 3/5 stars and described it as "a likable and technically impressive comedy-horror" that is "fantastically silly, often funny".

Comment: Interesting: a breath of fresh air among this mainstream crap like *Alien* and *Star Wars*. You have my +1.

Answer (score -5):

[**Star Wars: Holiday Special**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Holiday_Special).

Because what could be more fitting of a revenge to George Lucas for inflicting the prequels on us, than keeping alive the thing he wishes to hide in the ashes of history?

Full movie below

Comment: You have my +1. I quite like this.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a December film?

Comment: @Richard - we are outvoted :(   Lucase clearly bought himself a large following here.

Comment: @DVK - I think I'll watch it anyway :-)