# September Movie Event #2

Tags: discussion, movie-night

**Update:**

Both The Matrix and Westworld were tied on +4, however The Matrix has the most upvotes (10 vs 6) so it's selected as our winner for this event.

---

Our most recent chat movie event, the amazing fantasy film "Stardust" was a **complete and utter bust** with just three commenters and three lurkers, thus proving that my initial instinct to stick with **only scifi films** was totally and utterly correct :-P

With that in mind and undeterred by [rand al'thor's dismal failure](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7211/20774), it's now time to pick September's second chatroom Movie Event! (can I get a hell-yeah!!?).

As before, you need to pick your preferred **SCI-FI** film and post it as an answer below. Upvote the ones you like and the top answer (by Friday 25th September at 9pm UTC) will be selected as the winner. We'll then watch together on Saturday 26th September at 9pm UTC in the Mos Eisley chatroom.

Choose wisely and remember, all scifi film suggestions will be considered carefully, except those that turn out to be [shampoo commercials](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103222/what-sci-fi-show-is-this-gif-from/103224#103224).

[image]

Comment: For the record, I would've joined the Stardust event if it was at a time I could attend.

Comment: In fairness, Sunday seems to have been a bust. Although I [still blame Rand](https://mpetersmdc.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/multiple-fingers-pointing-blame-at-man.jpg), the choice of date/time is likely to have been an issue, hence moving it to slightly earlier on Saturday.

Comment: I would have been there for Stardust if you didn't pick a day I was out of town :(

Comment: I was there! I had to leave early though because of my holidays. I missed the last 45 minutes, but "Stardust" waiting for me to finish it. I posted a few suggestions for this upcoming weekend.

Comment: In the future, could you please create questions about what movie to watch with the feature-request tag, so that the special voting rule from http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta applies and we can vote on answers according to that?

Comment: @b_jonas there's no different voting mechanism based on tags. around here, votes always indicate agreement/disagreement regardless of tags. this seems to be true on most metas i've looked at.

Comment: The dismal failure was YOUR fault for arranging the event on a Sunday! :-[

Comment: I stand by my assessment. Your suggestion, your fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going for the hit 1999 film "[The Matrix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/)" starring Keanu Reeves, Laurence Fishburne and Carrie-Anne Moss. This film literally inspired a film revolution, introducing new effects techniques that are imitated (but not bettered) in pretty much every scifi flick since 2000.

Remember the days when all that anyone could ask was...

> What is the Matrix?

[image]

Comment: *It's the question that drives us.* +1

Comment: @Praxis - If people vote for this film, they can find out what.it.is.

Answer (score 5):

My second nomination is the 1980 classic, *Flash Gordon*.  It has everything:  Brian Blessed!<sup>1</sup>  Max Von Sydow!  Topol!  Timothy Dalton!  Richard O'Brien!<sup>2</sup>  Sam J. Jones!  A brilliant soundtrack by *Queen*!  Beautiful, incredibly unique backgrounds!  Boar worms!  Ridiculously bad acting!  Absurd dialogue!  A fight in the form of a bizarre alien football game!  This thing!

[image: this thing]

### Just look at the poster:

[image: poster]

It absolutely **screams** "Campy Sci Fi!"

### Look how big Brian Blessed's mouth is!

[image: It's enormous]

### Watch the video for the amazing theme song!

### Read how much of a cluster#%£@ the production was!  Screenwriter Lorenzo Semple, Jr. said:

> [Producer] Dino [De Laurentiis] wanted to make Flash Gordon humorous. At the time, I thought that was a possible way to go, but, in hindsight, I realize it was a terrible mistake. We kept fiddling around with the script, trying to decide whether to be funny or realistic. That was a catastrophic thing to do, with so much money involved... I never thought the character of Flash in the script was particularly good. But there was no pressure to make it any better. Dino had a vision of a comic-strip character treated in a comic style. That was silly, because Flash Gordon was never intended to be funny. The entire film got way out of control.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(film)#Production)

That's right - they weren't sure if the movie was a comedy or not, **even while they were filming it**.  The producer didn't care that the main character was about as complex as a piece of cardboard.  It was less like producing a film, and more like releasing a sack full of angry, drunken badgers into a kindergarten classroom just to see what would happen.<sup>3</sup>

### But it gets even crazier than that!  Sam J. Jones, the star and titular character, hated Dino De Lauretiis so much that he quit before post production began.  A voiceover actor had to dub most of Jones' lines, and no one can remember who that voiceover actor was:

> According to a 2012 interview in Maxim, Sam J. Jones had disagreements of some sort with De Laurentiis and departed prior to post-production<sup>4</sup>, which resulted in a substantial proportion of his dialogue being dubbed by a professional voice actor, whose identity is still a mystery.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(film)#Production)

Can you even imagine a film production so screwed up that no one thought to write down the name of the guy who recorded most of the lead character's lines?  Well, if you vote for this movie, you won't *have* to imagine it, because you'll see it for yourself!

### Freddie Mercury explains why we need to watch this movie:

- Flash is the Savior of the Universe
- He'll save every one of us
- He's a miracle
- King of the impossible
- He's for every one of us
- Stands for every one of us
- He'll save with a mighty hand every man, every woman, every child
- Just a man, with a man's courage
- You know he's nothing but a man, but he can never fail
- No one but the pure of heart may find the Golden Grail

## In light of this argument, I genuinely and emphatically believe that we *owe* it to Flash to watch this film.  After all, he **did** save every one of us.

<sup>1</sup>During filming, the battle scenes had to be reshot because [Brian Blessed was making "Pew!  Pew!" noises every time he fired a weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103262/44025), and you could see his mouth moving.  The director was not pleased.

<sup>2</sup>Best known as the writer-director of *Rocky Horror Picture Show*, in which he also played the role of the butler, Riff-Raff

<sup>3</sup>Seriously, it was ridiculous.  The producer referred to *Flash Gordon* as "the only improvised $27 million dollar movie ever made".  You can read all about it [here](http://io9.com/the-weirdest-things-you-never-knew-about-the-making-of-1571016187).

<sup>4</sup>The article linked in note <sup>3</sup> describes Jones' departure rather differently:  "At Christmas, he went to Los Angeles and never returned".  The producer was proud that he was responsible for the only major studio film that was completed with the star AWOL.

Comment: FLASH! AH AH SAVIOR OF THE UNIVERSE!!!!!! Queen is soooooooooooo awesome

Comment: YES. +1. I have to write 8 more characters before this comment can go through.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate Neill Blomkamp's "[District 9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1136608/)". A wonderful mix of low budget effects and larger-than-life space aliens living in a filthy ghetto in South Africa.

If you ever wondered what it would really be like when aliens arrive, this dystopian film gives us a glimpse into the future, 10 minutes from now.

[image]

Comment: Love District 9

Answer (score 4):

I'm renominating *Westworld*. With a score of 4, it is currently the highest voted movie from the last event, scoring higher than *Stardust*.

[image]

It's a classic sci-fi movie with an intriguing plot. With the TV reboot coming soon, it will help everyone get up to date with the original.

It also has a lot of stupid things and parts that don't make sense, so everyone can make fun of it, and that's always fun.

Comment: You have my +1. Great film

Comment: Great choice, @RogueJedi, +1.

Comment: Anything with yul brynner gets a +1, wish it could him as pharaoh though. MOOOOOOOOOSEEEEEESSSSSSSSS

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen this movie you absolutely want to see it.

**The Host (2006 film)**

[image]

It was suggested I include some info, but I don't want to spoil it for you, this will spoil the first ten minutes of the movie, so here goes:

The movie concerns a monster kidnapping a man's daughter, and his attempts to rescue her. According to the director, his inspiration came from a local article about a deformed fish with an S-shaped spine caught in Han River

There are sightings of a strange amphibious creature in the waterway, and the fish in the Han River are dying off because of water pollution. Six years later, in Seoul, Park Gang-du (Song Kang-ho) is a seemingly slow-witted man who runs a small snack-bar with his father, Hee-bong (Byun Hee-bong). Also with him is his daughter, Hyun-seo (Go Ah-sung), his sister, Nam-joo (Bae Doona), a national medalist archer, and his brother, Nam-il (Park Hae-il), a heavy drinking unemployed college graduate and former political activist.
While Gang-du is delivering food to some customers, he sees a crowd along the Han River. They witness a huge creature hanging from the Wonhyo Bridge, which then jumps into the water...from there everything goes haywire.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(2006_film):

> It was ranked one of the top films of 2007 on **Metacritic with a score
>   of 85.**
>
> The Host received critical acclaim, with a **93% "Fresh" rating on
>   Rotten Tomatoes.**
>
> ...13 million tickets had been sold, making it (at the time) the
>   **highest grossing South Korean film of all time.**
>
> It won several awards including Best Film at the Asian Film Awards and
>   at the Blue Dragon Film Awards.
>
> In addition to its opening in Cannes, among the most prominent were
>   the Toronto, Tokyo and New York film festivals.
>
> The film swept Korea's Blue Dragon Awards : The Host received five
>   awards, Go Ah-sung took Best New Actress and Byun Hee-bong was awarded
>   as Best Supporting Actor.
>
> The French film magazine Cahiers du cinéma ranked the film as 3rd
>   place in its list of best films of the year 2006 and 4th for the
>   2000-2009 decade.
>
> The Japanese film magazine Kinema Junpo selected it as one of the top
>   10 best foreign films of the year 2006. (Flags of Our Fathers won the
>   best foreign film of the year 2006.)
>
> Manohla Dargis of The New York Times wrote "The Host is a loopy,
>   feverishly imaginative genre hybrid about the demons that haunt us
>   from without and within."
>
> The filmmaker **Quentin Tarantino** included it in his list of **top 20
>   films** released since 1992 (the year he became a director).
>
> The film was also listed at #81 on Empire Magazine's list of The 100
>   Best Films of World Cinema.
>
> **Top ten lists:  The film appeared on several critics' top ten lists of the best films of 2007:**
>
> 2nd Ella Taylor, LA Weekly (tied with Manufactured Landscapes)
>
> 2nd V.A. Musetto, New York Post
>
> 4th Dana Stevens, Slate
>
> 5th Marc Mohan, The Oregonian
>
> 5th Mike Russell, The Oregonian
>
> 7th Desson Thomson, The Washington Post
>
> 9th Wesley Morris, The Boston Globe
>
> ***Awards and nominations:***
>
> **2006 Asia Pacific Film Festival**
>
> Best Supporting Actor - Byun Hee-bong
>
> Best Editing - Kim Sun-min
>
> Best Sound - Choi Tae-young
>
> **2006 Chunsa Film Art Awards:**
>
> Best Lighting - Lee Kang-san
>
> Technical Award - Jang Hwi-cheol
>
> **2006 Blue Dragon Film Awards:**
>
> Best Film
>
> Best Supporting Actor - Byun Hee-bong
>
> Best New Actress - Go Ah-sung
>
> Best Lighting - Lee Kang-san, Jung Young-min
>
> Audience Choice Award for Most Popular Film
>
> Technical Award - The Orphanage, EON (CG)
>
> Nomination - Best Director - Bong Joon-ho
>
> Nomination - Best Actor - Song Kang-ho
>
> Nomination - Best Supporting Actress - Bae Doona
>
> Nomination - Best Screenplay - Bong Joon-ho
>
> Nomination - Best Cinematography - Kim Hyung-koo
>
> **2006 Korean Film Awards:**
>
> Best Film
>
> Best Director - Bong Joon-ho
>
> Best Cinematography - Kim Hyung-koo
>
> Best Visual Effects - The Orphanage, EON
>
> Best Sound - Choi Tae-young
>
> Nomination - Best Supporting Actress - Go Ah-sung
>
> Nomination - Best Art Direction - Ryu Seong-hee
>
> Nomination - Best Music - Lee Byung-woo
>
> **2006 Director's Cut Awards:**
>
> Best Performers Award - Ensemble cast (Song Kang-ho, Byun Hee-bong,
>   Park Hae-il, Bae  Doona, Go Ah-sung)
>
> **2007 Asian Film Awards:**
>
> Best Film
>
> Best Actor - Song Kang-ho
>
> Best Cinematography - Kim Hyung-koo
>
> Best Visual Effects - The Orphanage, EON
>
> Nomination - Best Editing - Kim Sun-min
>
> **2007 Hong Kong Film Awards:**
>
> Nomination - Best Asian Film
>
> **2007 Baeksang Arts Awards:**
>
> Best Film
>
> Nomination - Best Actor - Byun Hee-bong
>
> Nomination - Best New Actress - Go Ah-sung
>
> **2007 Saturn Awards:**
>
> Nomination - Best International Film
>
> Nomination - Best Performance by a Younger Actor - Go Ah-sung
>
> **2007 Grand Bell Awards:**
>
> Best Director - Bong Joon-ho
>
> Best Editing - Kim Sun-min
>
> Nomination - Best Film
>
> Nomination - Best Actor - Song Kang-ho
>
> Nomination - Best Supporting Actor - Byun Hee-bong
>
> Nomination - Best Supporting Actress - Go Ah-sung
>
> Nomination - Best Cinematography - Kim Hyung-koo
>
> Nomination - Best Visual Effects - The Orphanage, EON
>
> Nomination - Best Sound - Lee Seung-chul, Choi Tae-young
>
> **2007 Busan Film Critics Awards:**
>
> Jury Prize
>
> **2008 Belgian Syndicate of Cinema Critics:**
>
> Nomination - Grand Prix

Answer (score 0):

**Time Bandits**

I'm nominating "Time Bandits" again as well as "The Host"

Very few movies are better than this one.

[image]

I still think we should watch "The Host" as most community members probably haven't seen it and it's a really enjoyable film. But if people want a classic, great writing, great storytelling, great acting, amazing cast, this is it!

Time Bandits is a 1981 British fantasy film co-written, produced, and directed by Terry Gilliam, and starring Sean Connery, John Cleese, Shelley Duvall, Ralph Richardson, Katherine Helmond, Ian Holm, Michael Palin, David Warner, and Craig Warnock.

On review aggregator website **Rotten Tomatoes, the film holds a 92% rating** based on 39 reviews, averaging an 8/10.

Comment: How can people downvote a movie with almost half of the former Pythons (Cleese, Gilliam, and Palin)?  And the producers include Gilliam and George Harrison (of Beatles fame).

Comment: (Also, Co-producer Denis O'Brien was Harrison's financial manager, although they had a falling out, which resulted in a lawsuit, and O'Brien paying Harrison a hefty sum of money)

Answer (score 0):

How about the 2014 film [*Snowpiercer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowpiercer)?

Director Bong Joon-ho brings us a superbly created science fiction film that sees the last remaining survivors of a sudden global-cooling stuck on a train that travels the entire world once per year. At the back of the train, the masses live in poverty and are controlled by a vicious and fascist police force. At the front, the few live in luxury. We follow protagonist Curtis Everett (Chris Evans) as he leads a revolt from the back of the train that intend to take the front by any means necessary.

A film with great action, fantastic performances, an inventive concept and full of fun little moments that you would never get in a Hollywood film, *Snowpiercer* is just a great film that I would want anyone to see, and actually made my list of [the must see films of 2014](http://screennerds.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/the-must-see-films-of-2014.html), in which I described it as "undoubtedly one of the strongest science fiction films released in years, at once an exercise in world building, an allegorical look at the class system and a great action film".

[image: Snowpiercer poster]

I've seen it three times now, and I can confirm that it is a **really, really, really good film**.

Comment: I love this movie, it's so awesome. But like you I've seen it so many times because it's in rotation on HBO or showtime. Not sure I want to watch it so soon again.

Answer (score -3):

My first nomination is the **hilarious** and very original independent Irish sci-fi/horror/comedy film *Grabbers*.

Without giving too much away, an alien monster is attacking a small island off the coast of Ireland, and the only way to survive is to get really, REALLY drunk.  Hijinks ensue.

[image: Poster]

> Rotten Tomatoes, a review aggregator, reports that Grabbers received positive reviews from 72% of 29 surveyed critics; the average rating was 6.3/10. Damon Wise of Empire film magazine described it as "a romantic but surprisingly scary monster movie that feels like a lost Amblin flick, shaken and stirred with a dash of The Guard. ... a finely crafted tribute to a long-lost style of filmmaking [that] stands up in its own right too." Matt Glasby of Total Film rated it 3/5 stars and called it "a bright, breezy Irish monster mash boasting gorgeous cinematography, appealing performances and great SFX". Gareth Jones of DreadCentral rated it 4/5 stars and said, "it is one hell of a good time that offers plenty of laughs, excellent characters and performances, and big slimy monsters." Jordan Hoffman of US cable channel IFC summed the film up as "a delightful romp", while Upcoming Movies gave it four stars and called it a "fun, monster movie roller coaster" with a "mix of laughs and scares". The Daily Telegraph‍ '​s Robbie Collin called it a "cherishable Irish B-picture ... with an unimprovable premise".  Kim Newman of Screen Daily said of the film: "Kevin Lehane's smart script is canny enough to sidestep the expectations of fans who might think they know how films like this are supposed to play out, while the monsters are as well-realised as anything in far more costly productions."  The Irish Times said, "Grabbers has an atmosphere all its own: the humour is earthy without being patronising; the action sequences are both absurd and properly exciting." Peter Bradshaw of The Guardian rated the film 3/5 stars and described it as "a likable and technically impressive comedy-horror" that is "fantastically silly, often funny".

Answer (score -3):

Why aren't we watching Star Trek Renegades?

Comment: Because it's crap?

Comment: @Richard I haven't seen it, but I imagine it's so bad it's good, or at least an easy target for mocking.

Comment: I've seen the start. It falls into that odd category of being so bad that it's simply bad.

Comment: What is this? I've never heard of it. Scratch that, I'm watching it now. thx +1 because anything star trek...and it's got tuvok and chekhov with the original actors in it.

Comment: I got about halfway through it last night. Okay I know it kind of sucks, but it's something new & is Star Trekish. Its kind of missing something. I'm not sure if it's the production, the acting, or what but it seems like when they're talking to each other there's pauses, as if they're reading a script from a piece of paper. Also Khan's daughter should be way more of a badass. The special effects are alright but again they're missing something. It also has the feel of being done on video instead of on film. They need to put it through a filter. But I appreciate the info & will finish it tonight

Answer (score -8):

2015-09-26 Saturday is the date of the TV premiere of the fantasy movie

> ***My Little Pony Equestria Girls: Friendship Games***

on Discovery Family.

This doesn't interrupt the, ahem, “regular” schedule of the *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* TV show, so season 5 episode 15: “Rarity Investigates!” will be broadcast on the same evening.  With those two, there's no need for any other movie for the night.  So no matter what you choose, I'll be watching these instead.

Please tag questions about the film or TV show with both [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim) and [my-little-pony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony).

Comment: I'm gonna downvote, not because I think it'll be bad, but because its A) Not scifi and B) Not accessible (most users won't/can't get access to Discovery channel.

Comment: stardust wasn't sci-fi either; it's fantasy, just like MLP. but yes, it may be more difficult for everyone to get access to it to watch together on the original air date.

Comment: @Richard: not live, but I'm sure there'll be ripped streams of the film within twelve hours after its airing, digitally encoded in various qualities.

Comment: @b_jonas - Indeed. But that doesn't help us on the night

Comment: I generally watch the latest episode near Saturday 20:00 UTC. By that time, my preferred encode is availble. I don't know when during the day the film is shown (someone should check), and it may take longer to process because it's longer, but it may be available for movie night.

Comment: There isn't enough "no" in the world for this.

Comment: Is this animated?