# There has been an awakening...another Movie Night! Force Awakens on Monday the 11th!

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

Arguably, the biggest event in science fiction this past year (or perhaps even the last several years) has been the theatrical release of ***Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens***.

[image]

Now that the film has been released for digital purchase (iTunes, Google Play, etc.) and will be released imminently on DVD / Blu-Ray, it's a great time to have a **movie night** in celebration.  (It was **@Jolenealaska** who suggested this during our [last movie night](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/), and we think it's a great idea!)

The event will take place in the SFF chatroom **[Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/)** at

## 22:00 UTC on Monday 11 April!

For reference, that's 3 pm PST, 6 pm EST, and 11 pm UK time (GMT+1).

(What's a "Movie Night", you ask?  Your question has been wonderfully answered [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7434/40294).)

Join us on the 11th to discuss, criticize, and possibly even enjoy the latest entry in one of the world's most popular and enduring science fiction franchises!

**NOTE:** We'll be watching the 2015 version, not the 1977 one.

Comment: Finally one I'm going to be okay spending money on! Now, to make sure I actually have the time!

Comment: @CreationEdge : Yay!!  Hope to see you there.  About making the time: *Do or do not. There is no try.*

Comment: I have a meeting that usually ends when this starts, so I'll probably be 15 min late.

Comment: @CreationEdge : Totally fine --- we'll be happy to re-sync for you when you arrive!  :-)

Comment: I know it's not a pun, but THWACK! anyway for that dig in your last sentence. ]:p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## At **17 watchers / lurkers** at the highest points, this was one of our most successful movie nights ever!!

Thanks to all of the attendees for making this an awesome movie night — it was a blast!

For those who are interested, the transcript starts [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198/2016/4/11/22-23).

As always, many thanks to **@AncientSwordRage**, **@Randal'Thor,** and **@Null** for advertising these events.

Comment: And most importantly, many thanks to **@Praxis** for organising the event!

Comment: How many watchers and how many lurkers?

Comment: @Richard At least 8 watching it all the way through: Praxis, Wad Cheber, CreationEdge, AncientSwordRage, Napoleon Wilson, Axelonet, CandiedMango, Jolenealaska, possibly also Himarm and Matthew Stevenson. Lurkers included Slytherincess, steelerfan, Ixrec, Politank-Z, and myself. (Apologies to anyone I forgot!)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Nice. I think the top number of commenters we had before was 10, but that included various CMs who were hanging around the room.

Comment: @Richard TFA is good at making new records ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to get it!

*The Force Awakens* is available on Redbox in the US for both DVD and Blu-Ray.

The full movie is generally available for $15 USD the DVD or $20 USD for the Blu-ray/Digital HD combo. Online retailers have those prices, and in-store mega marts generally have those prices until Fridays after the release (then they go up about $5, but Amazon, for instance, generally doesn't).

The digital release is available for full purchase on most major online video stores, including iTunes, Google Play, Vudu, and more.

Unfortunately, there no digital rental option yet.

**The UK physical copy is not available until April 18th. The digital release is on April 11th.** It'll run about £13.99 for HD and £9.99 for SD.

Please feel free to edit with EU/AUS/Other release dates. Hopefully they're before or on the 11th.

Comment: Under no circumstances should anyone get the film from piratebay, no matter how easy or straightforward it might be. [That would be naughty](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mao9vuEzdW1qdk0zgo5_250.gif).