# Movie Night! Nominate your favourite TERRIBLE comic book film!

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

Continuing our latest line of movie nights focused on [terrible films](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/), we invite you to nominate your favourite **TERRIBLE comic book film** for a group viewing!

Your suggestion should be:

- based on a comic book series and/or comic book character(s)
- readily available on DVD, Blu-Ray, or a digital streaming service (e.g. iTunes, Google Play)
- generally awful

**The more terrible it is, the better!**

(What's a "Movie Night", you ask?  Your question has been wonderfully answered [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7434/40294).)

The event will take place in the SFF chatroom **[Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/)** at

## 22:00 UTC on Sunday the 1st of May.

I'll kick off the voting with a suggestion or two.

**Voting closes at 22:00 UTC on Wednesday the 27th of April.  If the film you voted for wins, please make every effort to attend (or else your account will be closed and your rep will be donated to charity).**

---

By the way, even though we are talking about *terrible* films, we'll decide by ***highest*** number of votes rather than lowest number.  ;-)

---

## UPDATE: 3-way tie!

As of the close of voting, we have a three-way tie!  The winners are ***The Phantom*** (1996), nominated by @CreationEdge, ***Batman: The Movie*** (1966), nominated by @WadCheber, and ***Fantastic Four*** (2015), nominated by @RogueJedi.

So we'll be treated to a **triple of movie nights** focusing on these terrible comic book films!  Exercising my privilege as movie night organizer, we'll watch them in the following order:

- ***The Phantom*** **(22:00 UTC on Sunday 1 May)**
- ***Batman: The Movie*** **([22:00 UTC on Tuesday 31 May](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9672/))**
- ***Fantastic Four*** **([22:00 UTC on Thursday 28 July](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/))**

If you voted for one of these films, we hope to see you in Mos during movie night!  If you didn't vote, then we hope to see you too.  The more, the merrier as always!  :-)

Please note that we'll probably be watching these a few weeks apart, so as to accommodate other events.  In particular, we may propose other movie night themes in between!

Comment: How about comic book movies that were filmed but never released? I was thinking Roger Corman's *The Fantastic Four* (1994).

Comment: @RobertF : If they are legally available, then sure, feel free to suggest them.

Comment: Is this just a highest upvote thing again, or net votes?

Comment: @CreationEdge : We select the film with the highest net votes.

Comment: I nominate BATMAN v SUPERMAN: Dawn of Justice. Biggest disappointment of the year.

Comment: @NVZ I'd agree, but it can't be watched legally yet. Perhaps next time.

Comment: @RogueJedi I know, but I had to vent frustration here.

Comment: I'm un-[meta-tag:featured]-tagging this now since the voting is over. Let me know if you disagree :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor : All good.  I'll create separate meta notices when we decide on dates for the other two.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## WATCHED: Sunday 1st of May

### *The Phantom* (1996)

#### Available on Netflix in the US and for digital SD / HD rental on iTunes in US, Canada, and UK!

> The Phantom, descendent of a line of African superheroes, travels to New York City to thwart a wealthy criminal genius from obtaining three magic skulls which would give him the secret to ultimate power.

Purple. So much purple.

THE RING!

[image]

It has horse(s) in it!

[image: enter link description here]

OOOH LA LA, BILLY ZANE

[image]

Dual-wielding like a mad pro

[image]

Have confidence in your king of terrible comic book movies

[image]

Comment: We said terrible, this film is amazing (as far as) I remember. Childhood memories don't let me down!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I haven't seen it since childhood either!

Comment: Why do people have such a difficulty to understand the word "terrible"?

Comment: Foul - The Phantom was AWESOME!!!

Comment: @Omegacron *Was*.

Comment: Note: for those without access to US Netflix, this can also be rented digitally on iTunes in SD or HD for not a lot of money.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Can you edit that in?

Comment: @CreationEdge : Done!  :-)

Answer (score 9):

## WATCHED: Tuesday 31st of May

### *Batman: The Movie* [(1966)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(1966_film))

Available on Amazon Video for free with Prime membership (in the US).

[image]

#### Why should we watch this?

**1. Bat Shark Repellent Spray**
[image: shark]

**2. Batman running around with a bomb**
[image: bomb]
[image: bomb2]

**3.  Cesar Romero flying an umbrella**

[image: umbrella]

**4. Batman wearing his utility belt over a surgical gown (and the Super Molecular Dust Separator)**

[image]

Comment: ^_^ Plus their good fortune in freefalling into the National Foam Rubber Wholesalers convention. This is, in my opinion, still the best Batman movie ever released.

Comment: In my opinion, there are at least three live-action Batman movies much worse than this one. At least this one is funny on purpose.

Comment: The request was for terrible movies not utterly fantastic ones. -1

Comment: People may be getting confused and upvoting this for being awesome.

Comment: I think my favorite scene is the "what's yellow and writes?" riddle-solving scene, but I realize there isn't an awesome picture to go with that. There's also Alfred's disguise....

Answer (score 9):

## WATCHED: Thursday 28th of July

### [*Fantastic Four*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four_(2015_film)) (2015)

Why don't we watch a newer film, while the hate is still fresh in our minds?

[image]

*Fantastic Four* is described by many as the worst superhero movie of all time and is the most critically panned mainstream superhero film released post-2000. This unintentionally hilarious movie has it all: bad acting, plot-holes, poor directing, blatant continuity errors, special effects failures, no Stan Lee...

Oh, and this idiot:

[image]

> A jumble of predictable but also incoherent plot turns, dreadful dialogue, and unfortunate visual choices.
>
> Two distinctly different approaches to filmmaking are employed here and neither of them manages to eke out a victory over the other.
>
> I can't help but feel that this was another type of film, but someone put his hands on it and it all went to hell
>
> features subpar visual effects and one-dimensional characters, along with a story that lacks emotional depth or any meaningful subtext leading to the obligatory trumped-up finale.
>
> For now, the only big screen on which Fantastic Four deserves to be seen is the one in your living room, on a Saturday afternoon, on Syfy.
>
> There are so many things wrong with Fantastic Four . . . that you could never squeeze them all into a conventional film review.

The story of the film's incredibly troubled production is also highly entertaining. [This video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPowVAXtN3lVNpK_f7QXbgag5HobKnV3w) on it is great and I would highly recommend it.

**It's also easily available for rent or purchase on DVD, Blu-Ray, iTunes, Amazon, Google Play, and Playstation.**

Comment: I unfortunately saw this recently. While I could get it for free from my video store, I'd be wasting the free rental :O.

Comment: @CreationEdge Video stores still exist?

Comment: There's one in my town and I can't believe it! They seemed to have closed  everywhere else I've lived, but it persists! Great to have when Redbox has delays.

Comment: I shall repeat: I'd rather gouge my eyes out.

Comment: It was so bad, I nearly couldn't remember the movie. _"2015? Fantastic Four? When did that happen?"_ My brain is in full denial.

Comment: If you watch the first half and then stop watching and just *imagine* what the second half should be, this is a decent film.

Comment: @apollo Are you saying you've Fantastically Fourgotten?

Comment: @RogueJedi Dude...

Comment: I don't know how they can get some of these films so drastically wrong. It's not as if you can blame the lack of decent source material. I can't believe those scores, but then I've not seen it yet...

Answer (score 5):

## *Steel*

#### (1997, [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120207/), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_(1997_film)))

Shaquille O'Neal's foray into the superhero genre as John Henry Irons (a character introduced during DC Comics' seminal *Reign of the Supermen* series) was less than well-received.  It has a mere 12% on [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1078035-steel), where the critics agree that ***"Steel is a badly-acted movie that indulges not only in superhero clichés, but also the sappy TV-movie-of-the-week ones."***

Honestly, 12% is probably a lot more than it deserves.

[image]

Available on [DVD and Amazon Instant Video](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003G5K7RW).

Comment: For *X-Files* fans, this has Annabeth Gish (aka Special Agent Monica Reyes) in a laser-shooting wheelchair.

Comment: This might be *too* terrible.

Comment: I came here simply to nominate this film. +1 Praxis. +1.

Answer (score 5):

[Condorman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorman)

He can really fly!

[image: Condorman has wings]

Best bit: the hidden car reveal (see also trailer above).

[image: Car reveal]

And the car can go on water:

[image: Car floating]

A film for true geeks!

Comment: Terrible? How dare you! I loved this film when I was younger!

Comment: There's a Condorman comic? Other than the one in the movie I mean.

Comment: AFAIK just in the film. And I loved this movie as well. Does this disqualify this answer?! (Not a real life comic and a lot of us think it is good!)

Comment: @Wikis - Hopefully not. Because I was thinking of contributing my own favorite bad movie, which is comicbook-ish but doesn't actually have a comicbook (that I know of)

Answer (score 5):

The [Wild World of Batwoman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061191/), available for free on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdiXvz6Kmhc) via its MST3K treatment.

> In this zero budget cheapie a busty Batwoman enlists her beauteous bevy of Batgirls (when they are not dancing the jerk) to help her regain a mad scientist's invention (an atom bomb made out of a hearing aid) before a costumed ne'er-do-well, Rat Fink, can glom onto it for his own purposes.

[image]

Whatever else you want to say about it, it is undeniably terrible.

Comment: Is the original version available? Wouldn't it be difficult to snark it if it's already being snarked?

Comment: @RogueJedi The original version does not appear to be readily available. Some can handle multi-level snark, feel free to base your vote on your attitudes thereto.

Answer (score 4):

## *Catwoman*

#### (2004, [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0327554/), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catwoman_(film)))

Considered one of the worst films of all time, this movie fell flat on its face in its attempt to bring a stand-alone Catwoman to the big screen.

Let's rejoice in its awesome terribleness.

[image]

Available on [DVD and Amazon Instant Video](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001NAT05W).

Comment: This is your favorite?

Comment: @CreationEdge : I have a few other terrible comic book films I could suggest.  But this one is pretty amazing in its level of terribleness.  May the worst film win!  :-)

Comment: I've unfortunately made a personal commitment to never watch it. :(

Comment: @CreationEdge : No sane person would question your stance....

Comment: I somehow missed hearing about this movie when it was made, and first caught it when it debuted on HBO or Showtime or whatever channel had the misfortune of purchasing the rites. It literally took me half the film before I could definitively say if the titular "cat woman" was supposed to be the DC Comics Catwoman, or if it was somehow just a French story about a girl who decided to dress up like a cat. Truly an impressive feat. +1

Answer (score 4):

Superman IV

Perhaps to worst comic book movie of all time, poor plot, terrible effects and could be considered  the reason we didn't have a big comic book adaption for a number of years after.

Answer (score 4):

## *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II: The Secret of the Ooze*

#### (1991, [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103060/), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles_II:_The_Secret_of_the_Ooze))

In stark contrast to [this film](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9481/40294), which was well done and downright gritty, its sequel *The Secret of the Ooze* is a complete stinker.

Between the ill-fitting casting change for April O'Neil, the made-up Tokha and Rahzar (in place of Bebop and Rocksteady), the ridiculous "Super Shredder", the cringe-worthy Vanilla Ice cameo, and the lack of a coherent plot, there is little that is redeeming about this movie...but there is a lot to laugh at!

[image]

[image]

Available on [DVD and Amazon Instant Video](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000696I0).

Comment: Turtles in Time was so cool when I was a kid. Surprised you didn't do TMN III

Comment: @CreationEdge : I rewatched *TMNT III* not that long ago.  I found it incredibly boring, but not as terrible as some other films on this page!

Comment: Although I would probably find this move terrible now, it was one of my favorites as a kid.

Comment: @DCShannon : Oh, I loved it as a kid.  But having watched it recently, I can say it is unbelievably atrocious.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Tank Girl.

Tank.

Girl.

TANK GIRL!!

[image: I LOVE JET GIRL!]

Answer (score 4):

**The Spirit** (2008)

Rotten Tomatoes Score: 14%
[image: spirit]

We had all the makings for a good movie:

Frank Miller, Samuel L. Jackson, Scarlett Johansson, and Eva Mendes.

Comment: I remember being shocked in the cinema at how absolutely terrible this film is.

Comment: @Praxis my wife and I had the same reaction in the theater. I seem to recall a bit of fury mixed in with my shock.

Answer (score 4):

Batman and Robin
[image]
[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118688/), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Robin_(film))

Comment: This film never actually happened. It's a figment of your twisted imagination.

Comment: They originally wanted to have Patrick Stewart as Mr. Freeze, but eventually went with Arnie.

Comment: Also, many, many things make this movie terrible (recurring close-up shots of plastic bat nipples and superhero crotches, anyone?), but perhaps the worst is this film's idea of Bane.

Answer (score 3):

### *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles* [(1990)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles_(1990_film))

[image]

'Nuff said.

Comment: But this film is *awesome*.

Comment: Who do I bribe to get this film to win?

Comment: Why do people have such a difficulty to understand the word "terrible"?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'll take bribes for votes on films!

Comment: How does my comment have so many upvotes, but the suggestion only has 1 total upvote?

Answer (score 2):

[Captain America (1990)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103923/)

[Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/captain-america1990/) score: 9%

[image: Captain America (1990)]

[Available from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BCMT49I) on DVD & *Collector's Edition* BluRay!

(Google turned up various sites to stream it, but I'm not sure of their legality)

Comment: This film must be bad if I'm the first one to leave a comment :'D

Answer (score -1):

***Barbarella* (1968)**

[image]

Comment: A) Awesome, B) Not suitable for all viewers