# Holy reverse polarity Batman, what do we do now? Have a Movie Night on Tuesday, May 31!

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

As promised, we'll be watching the 1966 *Batman* film, one of the winners of our [terrible comic book movie vote](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/).  This slapstick take on the caped crusader stars Adam West as Batman, Burt Ward as Robin, Lee Meriwether as Catwoman, and Cesar Romero as the Joker!

[image]

The event will take place in the SFF chatroom **[Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/)** at

## 22:00 UTC on Tuesday 31 May!

For reference, that's 3 pm PST, 6 pm EST, and 11 pm UK time (GMT+1).

(What's a "Movie Night", you ask?  Your question has been wonderfully answered [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7434/40294).)

Please join us on the 31st to discuss, laugh at, criticize, and possibly even enjoy this decidedly terrible comic book film!

Also, note that this was nominated by **WadCheber**, our newest room owner in Mos Eisley.  **What better way is there to celebrate his new role than by gathering in chat to watch this film?!**

Here is WadCheber's [original post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9482/40294) nominating the film.

**Availability:**  Apart from DVD, this film is available on Amazon Prime and Google Play.

(Many thanks to **Randal'Thor** for reminding me to post this!)

Comment: I believe https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Batman?id=3KbfhzNXUbc is this movie on Google Play, though with the obviously wrong release date and lack of trailer it's hard to be certain. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Did they really misspell "villains" on the movie poster? In 1966? The mind boggles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm ready.

[image]

Even if this movie is amazing, not terrible.

Comment: Nice.  (But what an odd pairing of films....)

Comment: @Praxis I think they're both distributed by Fox or something. Also, Australia and New Zealand are weird.

Comment: Fair enough.  :-)

Comment: Also they both contain low-level violence!