# Movie Night! Fantastic Four: come watch this "malformed curio" on Thursday the 28th!

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

Completing our triple bill of [terrible comic book films](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/movie-night-nominate-your-favourite-terrible-comic-book-film) is 2015's universally-panned *Fantastic Four*.  Mustering a whopping 9% on Rotten Tomatoes, one of the site's resident critics declares it to be a

> poorly constructed, ineptly executed, flatfooted piece of Branded Product that plays as though it were written by a piece of software fed every superhero movie script to date and instructed to synthesize them.

Also:

> A jumble of predictable but also incoherent plot turns, dreadful dialogue, and unfortunate visual choices.

Another critic dismisses it simply as a

> malformed curio.

[image]

Let's get together to discuss, laugh at, criticize, and possibly even enjoy this decidedly terrible comic book film!  The event will take place in the SFF chatroom **[Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/)** at

## 22:00 UTC on Thursday 28 July!

For reference, that's 3 pm PST, 6 pm EST, and 11 pm UK time (GMT+1).

(What's a "Movie Night", you ask?  Your question has been wonderfully answered [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7434/40294).)

## <strike>Three</strike> Four Cheers for RogueJedi!

Note that this film was nominated by **RogueJedi**, and we're holding this event in honour of his excellent work organizing the **[Great Science Fiction Fantasy Showdown!](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-final-round/)**  So come out and say thanks to Rogue for all his hard work!

Here is Rogue's [original post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9489/40294) nominating the film.

**Availability:**  Apart from DVD, this film is available on Netflix (US and Canada at least), Amazon Prime, Apple Store, and Google Play.

*(Many thanks to **Randal'Thor** and **WadCheber** for reminding me to complete this run of terrible comic book films, and thanks to **Wad** and **AncientSwordRage** for helping to set up this particular event.)*

Comment: Can't be worse than Batman v. Superman

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just saw it listed on HBO Go last night, too. See here: http://www.hbo.com/movies/fantastic-four

Comment: @Hack-R BvS was better then Fantastic four

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

Please listen to the *Fantastic Four Medley* on an endless loop for the next 10 days in order to really get yourselves in the mood.

Answer (score 3):

## No.

Everyone else go along and enjoy yourself though!