# March Movie Event!! - Starship Troopers - March 18th at 11pm GMT (7pm EDT)

Tags: discussion, movie-night

Movie Night seems to have been a bit quiet recently, so to get things going again I'm nominating the ***single finest science fiction film ever made*** as our March Movie night film. That's right people, we're watching **[Starship Troopers!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_(film))** All are welcome to join in on **March 18th at 11pm GMT (7pm EDT)**

The more people that come to the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), the merrier it'll be and remember,

> **"Service guarantees citizenship!"**

### [FAQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhLTk.gif)

- **[What is a movie night?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/what-is-a-movie-night-really)**
- **Which version will we be watching?** The theatrical cut is currently available on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hw2sb8MXUAk) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TISWduNeto). There are also copies available on [DailyMotion](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2k6s2q), Amazon Prime and Hulu.  Amazon Prime members with the STARZ channel can watch it free, or use the STARZ channel 2-week free trial to watch it free.
- **What if I want to complain loudly about the film being worse than the book?** Then prepare to be pelted with popcorn!

---

### I'm doing my part!

Comment: There's a book adaptation of the movie? Oh, or maybe you mean the [book by the same name which is vaguely related to the movie](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36996/31936). They should [make a movie based on *that* book](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26367/31936).

Comment: You should rename the FAQ, *'Would you like To know more?'*. This is honestly one of the very best sci fi films out there. Brilliant mix of Cg and practical effects!

Comment: @Longshanks - Did you click the [FAQ](https://i.imgur.com/fdNkQiQ.gif) link?

Comment: Man, I have to try and figure out what time this in my timezone and that means subtracting a whole hour from EST. So much work...

Comment: @Valorum Ha! Niiice

Comment: Hmm, I scheduled the chat event for 11pm GMT but the event that was created shows the start time as 7pm Eastern. This seems to be accounting for the time change this weekend, after which the Eastern U.S. will be only 4 hours behind UTC. Just to be clear: are you targeting 11pm GMT / 7pm EDT or 6pm EDT?

Comment: Finally one on a weekend! It will be interesting to see if that improves attendance.

Comment: @Skooba - Don't underestimate the awesome drawing power of Starship Troopers.

Comment: Looks better than _The Phantom Menace_!

Comment: @CreationEdge - So you live in one of the flyover states then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we could be avoided by most flights if needed.

Comment: @Valorum It was scheduled to promote it starting tomorrow (apparently the default behavior is to start promoting the event 7 days in advance). I changed it to start promoting it sooner, and now I see it on the Community Bulletin.

Comment: @Null - cheers. I thought it was a little odd. Scheduled events are a nightmare to manage.

Comment: As I learned last time, it is apparently confusing to Europeans to use Am/PM. They expect military time.

Comment: I grew up across the street from Camp Arthur Currie at the tail end of the vietnam war (by then it was Currie Barracks, and later yet CFB Calgary). When I read Starship Troopers the first time, it was with the sound of Chinook helicopters flying over my house and the sight of Canadian soldiers practicing rappelling from said helicopters across the street. As a ten year old, it was a great way to introduce me to sci-fi.

Comment: Anything worth writing a wrap-up post about, either here or maybe on the blog if the chat was interesting enough?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I've wrapped up both the film and given my thoughts about future events and how best to publicise them

Answer (score 5):

**Movie night was a great success**

We had six active participants (The Dark Lord - First time contributor, MissMonicaE - First time contributor, Kyle Jones, Edlothiad - First time contributor and Himarm). That number goes up to seven if you include CreationEdge who joined us a few minutes after the film ended to say

> [Oh I missed the movie?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36134087#36134087)

We also had no less than 9 lurkers which brings the grand total to nearly 15 viewers!

---

**Funniest comment** goes to MissMonicaE for

> [Is there really this much public kissing in high school? I'm so glad I
> was homeschooled](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36130431#36130431)
>
> [image]

and The Dark Lord for

> [Time since last incident: 0 days.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36130957#36130957)
>
> [image]

---

The winner of the **'Captain Obvious' prize** goes to Himarm for

> [shower scene is always fun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36130796#36130796)
>
> [image]

and MissMonicaE for

> [Ladies love a man in uniform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36130581#36130581)
>
> [image]

---

**Honourable mention** goes to Edlothiad for

> [Lieutenant Dan?! oh wrong film](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36130630#36130630)
>
> [image]

---

### What did we learn?

- This film was chosen by diktat rather than a democratic vote on Meta.

Historically there seems to be little benefit in allowing the community to choose over simply announcing what film is being shown.

- The post was "featured" early (with the date, time and movie name in the title).

Placing it on the main board seems to have attracted no less than **six** users who've never come into chat before, one of whom then contributed to the event. The vote-count seem to have largely reflected the number of participants.

- Making it a featured event in chat seems to have had little impact.

Only two people "registered" for the event.

- Picking a film that was accessible online seems to have been a benefit.

At least three of the contributors were watching a version that was streaming from youtube rather than having to download their own copy.

- The date and time seem amenable (to most)

Placing it on a weekend evening appears to have been more effective than making it mid-week, something we tried last year with very limited success.

Comment: I'm debating having two meta posts, one to *choose* the film and a second to announce the winner and coordinate the date/time

Comment: "*Placing it on the main board seems to have attracted no less than six users who've never come into chat before*" - that's not counting the *dozens* of people who've briefly come into Mos in the last few weeks and lurked, presumably having followed the link from the sidebar, but had never been in there before.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes, I count the "lurker" numbers based on those who've commented in the 30 mins before the film starts or who enter chat during the films. There might be many more who came in earlier and just hung around but there's no way of telling

Comment: I'm not sure the number of registrations for the event can be used as an argument against the advantages of making it a chat event. I would assume (even though not know) from all the people who *do* see the chat event advertisement and might consider participating, there's still many who might not be too aware of the registration feature, let alone bother to use it.

Comment: @TARS - Making it a chat event can't possibly hurt, I just don't think it helps very much. Since it **is** a chat event, we should continue to do it as a matter of course

Comment: What makes you do your last deduction? Why do you think placing it on a weekend had any positive impact on the number of participators and wasn't just irrelevant (or counterproductive) but dimished by all the other positive factors?

Comment: @TARS - Again, I'm basing it purely on my own observations and prejudices based on the number of people telling me (in the weeks prior to a chat event) that they're sorry that they can't attend.

Comment: @TARS - We tried putting a few of them mid-week in 2015 and the attendance was very poor, usually only two or three participants and practically no lurkers.

Comment: You had people telling you they can't attend because of the weekend and this makes you think the weekend slot was more effective?

Comment: @TARS - No. Fewer people told me they couldn't attend the weekend slot. More people told me they couldn't attend mid-week

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, I made the breakdown? I was bummed I missed out. But I've been sick all week and totally forgot the the right schedule for this.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Never mind. You can help to choose the next one. The theme is going to be "Ladies' night" with extra upvotes for films that have strong female main characters and pass the [Bechdel test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test)

Comment: @Valorum - Conan the Destroyer.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Bechdel Test passed with flying colours and two main female characters. Red Sonja might be even better...

Comment: @Valorum - Red Sonja is a worthy backup.

Comment: I was going to suggest The Handmaid's Tale, because the book was great, but the trailer looks absolutely terrible.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - The film was OK. Not as good as the book.