# April Movie Night Special - It's Ladies' Night!

Tags: discussion, movie-night

### Update.

At midnight the votes were counted and verified by our judges. The clear winner with 23 points (20 upvotes + 3 bonus points) is MissMonicaE's [The Terminator](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10736/20774).

I'll be creating a new post shortly to formally announce the winner and confirm the date/time of our next Movie Night event in the [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) chatroom.

**You can continue to vote, but they won't be counted :-)**

---

<s>After the success of our [March Movie night](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10732/20774), it's time to choose a sci-fi/fantasy film for April's viewing pleasure. After consulting with absolutely no-one, I've decided that the theme for our next event will be "[**Ladies' Night!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtPgkuGhtC4&feature=youtu.be&t=6s)".</s>

### **Nominate your favourite film below and we'll watch it together.**

---

### Rules

- **Upvotes count as one point.** Final decision will be on the 31st March at midnight BST. **Downvotes will be ignored.**
- 1 additional point will be awarded for the following criteria;

  - The film is "[**F-Rated**](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=f-rated&mode=detail&page=1&ref_=kw_ref_key&sort=moviemeter,asc)" (*written by* **or** *directed by* **or** *starring women in a complex role*)
  - The film passes the [**"Bechdel Test"**](http://bechdeltest.com/) (*two **named** female characters talk about something other than a man*)
  - The film has been suggested by user who identifies as female.

---

### FAQ

**[Q. What is a movie night?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/what-is-a-movie-night-really)**
**A.** *Great fun(!)*

**Q.** **How do I nominate a film?**
**A.** *By posting an answer below. I'll append the additional points (if any) by edit.*

**Q.** **What if I'm a vile misogynist who wants to watch a film with [no women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(1982_film)) in it [at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Star_(film))?**
**A.** *Wait until May.*

Comment: @amaranth - Yes. Good luck finding a film that's F-Rated that doesn't pass the Bechdel test, BTW.

Comment: What is a complex role?

Comment: @TARS - According to the inventors of the rating, the character needs to be in a *"lead role on screen contributing significantly to the story"*. Grace Stamper (in Armageddon) would not quality, for example. You could remove her lines entirely and replace her character with a puppy.

Comment: Tempted to propose _Twilight_ :D It'd have a 2 point head start, but I can Imagine the number of downvotes :)

Comment: @gaĺlifreysn - We're only counting upvotes

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I'd upvote it. I've never seen it and I'd like the opportunity to see if it's as corny as everyone says

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be appropriate since I'll probably won't be able to attend. But I'll happily post a proposal :)

Comment: When I see this, the only thing that pops into my head is the song "Ladies Night" by Kool and the Gang ;)

Comment: If only Marvel had given Black Widow her own movie. I'M BITTER AND ALWAYS WILL BE.

Comment: @User22792 - I've got you covered. Click the link

Comment: @MissMonicaE - The problem with Black Widow is that her character is utterly two-dimensional, great as part of an *ensemble* cast but unimaginable in a stand-alone role.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - The date is TBC. I'll consult when we've got a film chosen. It'll probably be about the 8th April or maybe even the weekend after.

Comment: @Valorum I totally disagree! I want to know more about her backstory, especially why she defected and her past with Hawkeye. Also, her friendship with Hulk is interesting in light of how she's the most physically vulnerable of the Avengers (no armor, no mutant powers, smaller/weaker than Hawkeye, and generally women think more about physical vulnerability than men) and he's the most dangerous and out of control, but she still makes a point of trusting him. It's possible that this is all more fleshed out in the comics, but I think she deserves a film as well.

Comment: @TARS Consider the "sexy lamp test." A character who could be replaced with a sexy lamp at no damage to the plot doesn't count.

Comment: @Valorum Hahaha!  I didn't even notice that!!  +1 for putting the Kool and the Gang song on your link!  Nice!!

Comment: Why are you only counting up votes?

Comment: @Skooba - Because only upvoters are going to come to the thing. Downvoters can vote with their feet.

Comment: @Valorum I dunno about that... if there is a movie that ***I*** want to watch I will up-vote that, and if there is a movie I *really* do not want to see I will down-vote it.

Comment: @Skooba - If you really don't want to see it, no-one is making you :-) I'm assuming that upvotes mean "*I approve of this film **and there's a good chance I'll come see it on the night***"

Comment: @Valorum Should there be a fourth extra point if the movie is targeted to a female audience? Although I wonder if audience targeting would be overly subjective.

Comment: I don't think that Bechdel Test should be applied too strictly.  Doesn't it matter how the masculine component of the discussion is featured?  E.g. _Teeth_ would be out, but how would _The Lion, The WItch, And The Wardrobe_ fare?  Well, it doesn't seem to've limited the nominations all that much, but none of these strike me as especially characteristic.

Comment: @can-ned_food - I felt that the F-rating and the Bechdel test were tests that could be applied objectively.

Comment: I’m fine with this as long as we keep it to one Ladies Night out of twelve, otherwise it’s clearly a case of militant feminists trying to take over everything.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I'm open to suggestions regarding themes. Since I seem to be the one who (mainly) organises 'movie night', I shall try to mix it up over the next few months to see if theming encourages participation

Comment: @Valorum suggested themes: post-apocalypse; zombie apocalypse; mass surveillance; infectious disease; rebellion/revolution; foreign films; racial-/ethnic-minority leads.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Ugh, not zombies.  Anyways:  We have many names here that indicate a feminine user profile — there ought be more of them here suggesting titles.  Good ones.  Not zombies.  :-P

Comment: @can-ned_food Hey, 28 Days Later is great. I would downvote WWZ, though.

Comment: One of them should be Opposite Month, where you actually choose the movie which received the most **downvotes**.  Of course, you would declare this to be the case by oppositely *not* declaring it.

Comment: @can-ned_food We could have a zombie theme where suggested films gain extra points for being proposed by a user who identifies as a zombie.

Comment: Can I propose Starship Troopers?

Comment: @Edlothiad - I'd rather people didn't propose any movies that we've had in the past 12 months.

Comment: @Valorum, but it was good, everyone needs to see it!

Comment: Wanted to nominate _Kill Bill_, for it has a badass female protagonist. Alas, not science fiction nor fantasy :(

Comment: WTF? 12 answers and nobody nominated *Slave Girls From Beyond Infinity*?

Comment: @user14111 Why not nominate it yourself instead of complaining that nobody else did?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Not complaining, merely wondering. I just don't care enough about what movie a few random people are going to watch, to go to the bother of posting an answer.

Comment: yippie, Hurrah ^_^

Comment: @ABcDexter - What are you so happy about?

Comment: @Valorum nothing * *giggles* * :)

Comment: While I probably won't have time to join you, maybe you can check whether one of https://letsgaze.com https://www.synaptop.com/how-to-watch-movies-with-friends http://syncplay.pl https://www.rabb.it https://www.watch2gether.com can help keeping in sync

Comment: Militant feminists ...

Comment: @Zommuter - Watch2gether seems a good option since this film is available online. I'll use it on the night.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - Are you happy now? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widow_(2021_film)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I nominate [The Terminator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/?ref_=nv_sr_2), which stars Linda Hamilton (and I guess some unimportant jock-y type man?) and also passes the [Bechdel Test](http://bechdeltest.com/view/1418/the_terminator/). Some claim it might be [the mother of all feminist action movies](https://booktrib.com/2015/06/is-terminator-the-mother-of-all-feminist-action-movies/), although I'm categorically skeptical of such sweeping claims. But I've never seen it and I'd like to.

[image: Linda Hamilton and Sarah Connor]

---

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - [**Passed**](http://bechdeltest.com/view/1418/the_terminator/) (Sarah speaks to her roommate and several work colleagues about assorted subjects).
- **F-Rated** - **Passed**. The film's lead actor is a waitress.
- **Nominated female** - **Passed**.

(**+3**)

Comment: Already on an impressive +4 including my upvote.

Comment: I would think that T2 would have a stronger female lead in Sarah Connor being a _complete_ bad ass in that movie over the first one,  but the first Terminator is also awesome :)

Comment: @user22792 - Feel free to nominate it. You'll get +1 from me.

Comment: @Valorum Well...I don't know.  I don't think that Sarah Connor has an actual conversation with another female.  I want a +3 score, man!! ;)

Comment: Sarah has multiple conversations with her roommate about the roommate's boyfriend, at least one conversation about their iguana (which only counts towards the test if the iguana is a female), and one conversation about the news report of other Sarah Connors being killed (I don't know if it matters that the killings were committed by a robotic man).  In any case, you have my +1.

Comment: Sarah is more a focused character in this one than in the second, if not precisely the lead.

Comment: This has my vote, and I haven't seen it in ages. I'll make it for this one. (I'm a woman, so my vote should count twice!)

Comment: Haven't we already watched *Terminator* as part of our film of the month(ish) club? I could swear it was one of the first ones up. That said, around the same time the film club started, I - on my own - watched *Terminator 2* for the first time, so maybe I'm confused. I'm wondering, though, in general, if we ought to choose a film we've already seen as part of the film club? Meaning, do we want to keep seeing the same movie multiple times? I don't think it's a huge big deal, but others might care more. :)

Answer (score 12):

I, a fellow SFF girl lounging in yonder topmost tower, would like to nominate James Cameron's *The Abyss*, an excellent sci-fi film circa 1989 with a female co-protagonist (who is an engineer), a strong supporting cast, and an exciting, mega-adventure story. Let the Wiki tell you about it!

### ***The Abyss***

***The Abyss*** is a 1989 American science fiction film written and directed by James Cameron, starring Ed Harris, Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio, and Michael Biehn. When an American submarine sinks in the Caribbean, the US search-and-recovery team works with an oil platform crew, racing against Russian vessels to recover the boat. Deep in the ocean, they encounter something quite unexpected.

[image: Movie poster for James Cameron's *The Abyss*]

[image: Screen shot from James Cameron's *The Abyss*]

- Ed Harris as Virgil "Bud" Brigman, Deep Core's foreman and Lindsey's
  estranged husband.
- Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio as Dr. Lindsey Brigman, designer of the
  rig and Bud's estranged wife.
- Michael Biehn as US Navy SEAL Lieutenant Hiram Coffey, the commander
  of the Navy SEAL team.
- J.C. Quinn as Arliss "Sonny" Dawson
- Leo Burmester as Catfish De Vries, a worker on the rig and a Vietnam
  veteran Marine who is skeptical of the SEALs.
- Kimberly Scott as Lisa "One Night" Standing
- Todd Graff as Alan "Hippy" Carnes, a conspiracy theorist who believes
  that the NTIs have been covered up by the CIA. He carries a pet rat (Beanie) on his shoulder.
- John Bedford Lloyd as Jammer Willis
- Chris Elliott as Bendix
- Capt. Kidd Brewer Jr. as Lew Finler

**PASSES BECHDEL TEST:** YES
**F-RATED:** YES
**FEMALE-SPONSORED:** YES (I, Slytherincess, identify as female)
**OTHER:** Woman of color in a STEM role: Lisa "One Night" Standing. Just thought I'd note this.

### **SLYTHERINCESS'S FAVORITE LINES OF DIALOGUE:**

HIPPY: [Is going on about some conspiracy or another]
CREW MEMBER: Hippy, you think *everything's* a conspiracy!
HIPPY: [Genuinely perplexed at this comment] Everything is.

### **MISCELLANEOUS**

*The Abyss* was one of James Cameron's earlier films and filming it wreaked enough havoc that perhaps it ought to have been called [*The Abyssmal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Abyss#Principal_photography). (Thank you! I'll be here all week ...). Mainly, it required filming equipment and techniques that had not yet been invented, requiring Cameron to invent what he needed. There was a lot of strife on set (see link above). Main photography took place in an abandoned nuclear power plant in South Carolina (Duke Power?).

Nevertheless, *The Abyss* is truly an excellent film which I would highly recommend. The co-protagonist, played by Mary Elizabeth Mastrontonio, is smart, self-sufficient, brave, and work-focused. While a romance between her and co-protagonist Ed Harris kind of dances amongst the scenes, it is by no means the focal point of the story; I found myself not really caring whether the two protagonists would get together romantically. Either way would have been fine.

For 1989 (Leave a comment if you were around in 1989!) the effects are very good. An especially breathtaking moment comes when:

> The oil rig is being pulled by debris toward the underwater shelf that, should the rig go over the lip, leads straight down to the abyss -- miles and miles of dark water, ready to doom any human. This is a spectacular action scene!

[Check out the trailer for *The Abyss*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zbpL3LeW7k)

and

Please consider voting for *The Abyss*!

Comment: This is available on Amazon Video with a STARZ subscription (or the free trial if you haven't used it yet).

Comment: Here I was going to ask why you hadn't nominated one yet — and you chose this.  :'(

Comment: Oh, nice!  I didn't even think about this!  Good suggestion :)

Comment: I haven't seen this, and it has Ed Harris and Michael Biehn! Updoot

Comment: @can-ned_food -- What would you have had me nominate instead?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who upvoted my nom! That said, let's all enjoy *The Terminator* when movie night rolls around -- it's a great flick! :)

Comment: At first I thought you wrote “upvoted my mom”.  **/8-[**  Anyways, if I recommend a nomination, what's the point?  I was just never fond of _The Abyss_, that's all.

Comment: @can-ned_food -- Oh, that's too bad, seriously, that you don't like *The Abyss*. It's one of the movies that got me interested in sci-fi, albeit it not hardcore, as opposed to fantasy, which I have always been a huge consumer of. I thought about *Star Wars - A New Hope*, but I felt it just didn't quite fit the parameters of the contest and would be considered overplayed. I asked what you thought I would've recommended instead of *The Abyss* just because you seemed surprised that that was the movie I picked. I was just curious as to what you were expecting I might recommend is all. :)

Comment: @tobiasvl -- They are so young! Also, there's the double plus of Michael Biehn's mustache, which is an entity unto its own ;P  :)

Answer (score 11):

I nominate [**The Fifth Element**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/) Starring Milla Jovovich.

[image: The Fifth Element]

---

**Extra Point Score**

- **Bechdel Test** - **[Failed](http://bechdeltest.com/view/22/the_fifth_element/)** (Leeloo [speaks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JljZbjpvjmE) to several *unnamed* females and has a telepathic connection with a female character but doesn't have a conversation with a *named* female character).
- **F-Rated - Passed** The film's plot revolves around the titular "Fifth Element", Leeloo herself.
- **Nominated female - Passed.**

**(+2)**

Comment: leeloo dallas, multi-pass

Comment: @Himarm - Muuul-teeeee-paaaaas.

Comment: I think she speaks to Diva Plavalaguna, and she speaks to the woman at the airport gate.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - She doesn't speak to the Diva and the woman at the gate is *unnamed*. The Bechdel Test requires an exchange of words with another actress named in the film.

Comment: @amaranth - Telepathy doesn't count, I'm afraid. It has to be a *verbal* conversation (an exchange of words). I think the test would accept it if we could hear the telepathic words.

Comment: [Multi pass](http://www.multimatedebreker.nl/uploads/images/depas.png)!

Answer (score 9):

Late entry here: **[The Hunger Games](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392170/)** starring Jennifer Lawrence.

[image: Poster]

It's [on-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hunger-games) and pretty damn good. As someone who rarely appreciates film adaptations of books, I thought this one did very well, both in casting the characters and in catching the tone and mood of the post-apocalyptic dystopia of Panem. It's one of few films I've watched multiple times, and one of very few which can genuinely move me emotionally. Starting from the reaping scene near the very beginning, this film is packed with emotion as well as action and extreme tension.

---

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - **[Passed](http://bechdeltest.com/view/3138/the_hunger_games/)**: Katniss speaks to Prim about the Games, to Rue about blowing up the supplies, to Clove about Rue, ...
- **F-Rated** - **Passed**: the film's lead is a strong female character.
- **Nominated female - <s>Failed</s> Passed** (Co-sponsored by user [MissMonicaE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/73099/missmonicae)).

(**+3**)

Comment: I support it! But I'm an [apache helicopter](http://i.imgur.com/JSeLmGY.jpg)

Comment: I'll cosign this, if I'm allowed to add my female privilege to more than one nomination.

Comment: @MissMonicaE If you did, would it re-inforce the old quip that women can multitask and men cannot?

Comment: @MissMonicaE Anyone can post one than one nomination themselves, so I don't see why not.

Comment: Co-sponsoring is fine and can be done multiple times.

Comment: The first film is the most boring in the series.

Comment: @CreationEdge I agree, but it makes more sense to watch the first one in case some of our attendees aren't familiar with the franchise.

Answer (score 7):

I'll toss my hat in the ring with [*The Thing (2011)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(2011_film)).

[image]

#### Background - *The Thing (1981):*

*John Carpenter's 1981 masterpiece*, The Thing, *begins with a Norwegian helicopter pursuing a husky across the frozen landscape of Antarctica. After cornering the dog outside an American research station, the helicopter's frantic and inexplicably aggressive crew are killed and the Americans head to the Norwegian base in an attempt to uncover what led the Norwegians to behave so strangely.*

*The Americans find the Norwegian base a smoldering ruin, with evidence of a fierce battle and the gruesome discovery of a frozen corpse, clutching a straight-razor, with its wrists and throat slit.  A hollowed out block of ice adds to the mystery, and the Americans eventually learn that the base had been set up to excavate an alien spacecraft from the ice.*

*As it turns out, the "dog" the Norwegians were trying to kill is actually a hostile alien creature that kills other lifeforms, transforms into an exact duplicate of the victim, and attempts to assimilate everyone it encounters.  The Americans realize that they must destroy the monster, but paranoia sets in as they try to work out who is a real human and who is an alien impostor...*

### The Nomination:  *The Thing (2011)*:

A prequel to the 1981 film, this movie explores the events that led up to the beginning of Carpenter's iconic classic.  The fractured bits of evidence found by the American team were never really explained in the original movie, but they are now.  The Norwegian base's grim fate is finally laid out for the audience, and the movie ends exactly where the 1981 film begins.

It would be impossible for any prequel or sequel of Carpenter's film to match the greatness of the original, so we can forgive *The Thing (2011)* for being good rather than amazing. But despite its flaws, the movie is extremely watchable; it is essential viewing for any fan of the original, and it couldn't have happened without some brilliant work from hardcore *Thing*-fans.<sup>1</sup>

**With strong performances from the entire cast<sup>2</sup>, and especially impressive showings from Mary Elizabeth Winstead (Kate Lloyd), Joel Edgerton (Carter), Jørgen Langhelle (Lars), and Stig Henrik Hoff (Peder), this may not rival its predecessor in quality or significance, but it is a thoroughly enjoyable film with a talented cast, and the story is centered on a resilient, intelligent, dynamic female lead.**

---

### Extra Point Score:

- **Bechdel Test - [Passed](http://bechdeltest.com/view/2764/the_thing/)**. (Kate and Juliette speak about stars, their reaction to discovering a flying saucer and the titular 'Thing' itself).
- **F-Rating - Passed**.  The protagonist is a dynamic woman who goes from paleontologist to alien-killer with relative ease; she was apparently modeled on one of the greatest female leads in Sci-Fi history, Ripley from the *Alien* franchise.
- **Nominated by a Female - Failed**.

**(+2)**

---

---

<sup>1</sup> *The original film's Norwegian base set was destroyed when production wrapped up, and no blueprints were kept.  The director of the 2011 prequel was at a loss as to how to recreate the base accurately, until the members of the fan site [Outpost #31](http://www.outpost31.com/movie/maps.shtml) spent hundreds of hours pouring over every frame of the 1981 film in faithful, painstaking detail, performing all sorts of calculations, and producing precise plans for the base as it appeared in the Carpenter film.  The production team for the prequel used these fan-made schematics to construct the set we see in this film.*

<sup>2</sup> *The casting department deserves credit for filling the roles of Norwegian characters with actual Norwegian actors - it might seem like the most obvious option, but Hollywood insists on jamming American/British actors into every major role, regardless of the character's in-universe nationality; this is how we end up with Scarlett Johansen starring in* Ghost in the Shell *despite the fact that her character is Japanese.  If the production team had followed this trend,* The Thing (2011) *would have been deprived of one of its most likable moments - the Norwegian researchers celebrating their discovery by spontaneously singing* Sámiid Ædnan, *Norway's contribution to the 1980 Eurovision song contest; the cast members came up with the idea, and chose* Sámiid Ædnan *because it would have been familiar to a Norwegian in 1981, when the movie takes place.*

Comment: +1 for justifying _The Thing_ for Ladies Night ;)

Comment: The original wouldn't have been eligible.

Comment: I'm not sure why I haven't seen this remake yet. I think maybe I assumed it also had foreigners portraying Norwegian actors like the original, which – for me, as a Norwegian – is nearly unwatchable at times.

Answer (score 6):

This one is definitely on the obscure side, but I nominate [Paperhouse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098061/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt).

[image]

**Plot Summary**

*Paperhouse* is a dark fantasy centered around a young British girl named Anna (Charlotte Burke).  Anna, easily bored with school and unhappy with her home life, is given to drawing in her composition book. Most recently, she's drawn an oddly shaped house that strikes her fancy. As she develops a mysterious fever, Anna begins to visit the house and the world it lies in her dreams.  As her illness inexplicably worsens, the link to the dream world both strengthens and takes an increasingly sinister turn.  Co-written and based on the novel *Marriane Dreams*, by Catherine Storr.

**Nomination**

This one is an interesting little gem of a film.  It's a stark, visually stunning film with an excellent performance by Charlotte Burke.  Roger Ebert described the film as having Bergman-like qualities (his detailed and not entirely spoiler-free review can be found [here](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/paperhouse-1989)) in its effective simplicity.  Though her primary interaction in the dreamworld is with a male character, there are extensive dialogues between Charlotte and her mother, her classmates, as well as her doctor (played by veteran British actress Gemma Jones).

**Finding the film**

Obviously, this is not a well-known, mainstream film.  I have been able to find two sources for the movie, however.  It is available for streaming on Amazon, and - for the time being - it can be found on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kidKTsAPzic).

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - Passed (Anna has a considerable number of conversations with named characters including her mother, Kate and her best friend Karen).
- **F-Rated - Passed.** The film's lead actor is a schoolgirl and the film's writer was a noted female novelist.
- **Nominated Female - Failed**

**(+2)**

Comment: Hi RedshirtCrewmember. Remind me, are you male or female?

Comment: Or smizmar, maybe?

Comment: @Valorum.  Hi, Valorum.  I'm male.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate [The Princess and the Frog](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780521/), a fantasy movie about a woman hustling like crazy to start her own business. What could be better than that?

[image: The Princess and the Frog poster]

I'll tell you what: a fantasy movie about a woman hustling like crazy to start her own business *and also everything is full of jazz music*. That's what.

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - [Passed](http://bechdeltest.com/view/562/the_princess_and_the_frog/) (Tiana speaks extensively with her mother, Eudora about her goal of opening a restaurant).
- **F-Rated - Passed.** The film's lead actor is Tiana, a singing chef
- **Nominated Female - Passed**

**(+3)**

Comment: I'm not a big fan. I've tried to watch it a couple of times and never made it past the first twenty minutes.

Comment: I like the Jazz!

Comment: @amaranth - Passes on both

Comment: Let me guess — she was going to serve–up the frog in her cajun restaurant?

Answer (score 4):

I nominate [**Red Sonja**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Sonja_(film)) starring Brigitte Nielsen (<sub><sup>and Arnold Schwarzenegger</sup></sub>).

The film has a strong female lead who's easily the equal of her male co-star and features Sandahl Bergman (who played Conan's love interest in the original Conan the Barbarian movie) as the evil Queen Gedren.

[image]

---

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - [**Passed**](http://bechdeltest.com/view/418/red_sonja/) (Gedren speaks to Sonja about a magical talisman).
- **F-Rated** - **Passed**. The film's lead actor is a female warrior.
- **Nominated female** - **Failed**.

(**+2**)

Comment: For those downvoting, I hope you realise that it's purely symbolic. I'm only counting upvotes...

Comment: You get a +1 from me!  I frigging love this movie!

Answer (score 4):

I'll suggest *[100 Feet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0899128/)*.

[image: 100 Feet DVD cover]

> After Marnie Watson kills her abusive husband in self-defense, she is condemned to house arrest... only to discover that the house is possessed by the enraged and violent spirit of her dead husband.

And honestly, it's one of the best productions I've ever seen distributed by The Asylum.

**Trailer**

---

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - [Passed](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=100-feet) (Marnie has several conversations with her ex-con friend about the difficulty of dealing with the outside world).
- **F-Rated - Passed.** The film's lead actor is female, although it is a limited cast admittedly.
- **Nominated Female - Failed.**

**(+2)**

Comment: Alternately, another haunted house film: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN0HVJ5tkIM

Comment: I've replaced your video because it didn't support embedded playback

Comment: This looks like a horror film to me, not speculative fiction. (I know horror gets lumped in with SF&F all the time, but it's a fundamental misunderstanding of both genres to confuse one with the other.)

Comment: :) Ghosts. That makes for Fantasy for me.

Comment: "best Asylum film" is a bit like "most enjoyable root-canal surgery".

Comment: @Valorum" Eyeh, but they do occasionally do good films. This is one of the ones that was not a knock-off (although, funnily enough, someone delivered a second "house arrest in a haunted house" film a few years later with *Housebound*.

Answer (score 3):

I nominate [***Twilight***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_(2008_film))

[image]

Who hasn't heard of this awesome movie?!

A young girl named Bella Swan starts a new school, and learns her new classmate Edward is not what he seems...

It appears that the reception for this film has been mixed - some have certainly been inspired by Bella's character, while others blamed the film for the heroine being too inactive.

Eh, I guess we can see for ourselves! :)

---

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - [**Passed**](http://bechdeltest.com/view/501/twilight/) (Bella and her mother talk about moving home).
- **F-Rated** - **Passed** (lead actress, director, scriptwriter, source novel writer are all female)
- **Nominated female - <s>Failed</s> Passed (now co-sponsored by user [Martha](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/348/martha))**.

(**+3**)

Comment: For those downvoting, I hope you realise that it's purely symbolic. I'm only counting upvotes...

Comment: You've got my +1. After all this time, I'd quite like to see what all the fuss is about.

Comment: I was going to nominate this, but Gallifreyan got there first. Can I give it my female-nomination +1?

Comment: @amaranth - And shall get an extra +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

I nominate [**Terminator 2: Judgement Day**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day).

[image: terminator 2]

From Wikipedia:

> Terminator 2 follows Sarah Connor (Hamilton) and her ten-year-old son John (Furlong) as they are pursued by a new, more advanced Terminator, the liquid metal, shapeshifting T-1000 (Patrick), sent back in time to kill John Connor and prevent him from becoming the leader of the human resistance. A second, less advanced Terminator (Schwarzenegger) is also sent back in time to protect John.

---

### Extra Point Score

- **Bechdel Test** - [Passed (*dubiously*)](http://bechdeltest.com/view/847/terminator_2:_judgement_day/) (Sarah has a brief conversation with Sarah (and Miles) Dyson about the future).
- **F-Rated - Passed.** The film's lead actor is a waitress-turned-terrorist.
- **Nominated Female - <s>Failed</s> Passed (co-sponsored by [User22792](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792/user22792))**

**(+3)**

Comment: @amaranth #scarred

Comment: @amaranth Hehehe!  I didn't even mean it in a naughty way!  Y'all just took it that way :P

Comment: I'll just stick [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51337?m=35633879#35633879) and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/51337?m=35633929#35633929) here and walk away...

Comment: Does viewing order matter much for Terminator?

Comment: @MissMonicaE not _that_ much, but it does have a bit of a plotline. I think it would be okay to only watch 2 though.

Comment: @MissMonicaE It's about the same as with any movie sequel.