# "Ladies Night" Movie Night - The Terminator. Tonight!! (April 15th) at 10pm UTC / 11pm BST/ 6pm EDT

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

The clear winner in our [quest to select a 'Ladies Night' movie](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10734/april-movie-night-special-its-ladies-night) (with 20 upvotes and an additional three bonus points for being nominated by a [female user](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/73099/missmonicae), having a main female character and passing the [Bechdel Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test)) was the 1984 film classic '**The Terminator**', starring Linda Hamilton and Arnold Schwarzenegger.

**We'll be watching the film together in the [Mos Eisley chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) on April 15th at  10pm UTC (11pm BST, 6pm EDT)**.

### [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test)

- **[What is a movie night?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/what-is-a-movie-night-really)**
- **Which version will we be watching?**
  The theatrical cut is available (to purchase) on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fN82upbGPo&oref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-fN82upbGPo&has_verified=1) and [Vudu](http://www.vudu.com/movies/#!content/140350/The-Terminator) and you can also watch the movie online on DailyMotion [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2dh0ok_the-terminator-1984-full-movie-watch-online_shortfilms) and [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3qv4iy).
- **How do I make sure I'm in the same place as everyone else?**
  We'll be hosting a copy of the film on [watch2gether.com](https://www.watch2gether.com/), a video-sharing platform. All you need to do is click the link (that'll be provided on the day) and it'll take care of synching the video for you. Alternatively, you can just wait for me to tell you when to start.
- **What if I want to complain loudly about Arnold's inability to act or speak properly?**
  Then in the immortal words of the Terminator,

  > **"F٭ck you, A٭٭hole".**

Comment: 3:30AM IST. Thank you very much. I love to take full night's sleep.

Comment: @ILoveYou - Can't please everyone, I'm afraid.

Comment: @amaranth - What could possibly be more important?

Comment: [Meeting time for April Movie Night](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2017&month=4&day=15&hour=22&min=0&sec=0&p1=211&p2=136&p3=179). _(TIP: Iceland follows [UTC all year round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%C2%B100:00#As_standard_time_.28all_year_round.29), among some other countries, making it a convenient location selector when "UTC" is unavailable.)_

Comment: I probably also can't make it :(

Comment: @MissMonicaE - That's a shame since it's your pick. Hmm. That's at least two refusals so far. Perhaps a different day/time would be better? There's nothing to stop us from moving it...

Comment: @Valorum I'll be doing Easter stuff, I'm afraid (and visiting my sister the next weekend, so I may come under "can't please everyone").

Comment: @MissMonicaE - On reflection, Easter weekend may not be the ideal time... Hmm. Let me have a think

Comment: Can't make the 15th either. Going to have to be a late night watch after everyone's seen it again I guess.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I'm gonna move the date. It's not proving popular.

Comment: Before the 14th? Cool, glad we're agreed! :-P

Comment: @Edlothiad - I was thinking possibly the evening of the 21st or 22nd

Comment: I'm sure others will make it, but I most likely won't, either way it'll be a good un!

Comment: @Valorum Why wait so long? Since the film is already chosen, you could schedule it for some time next week.

Comment: @amaranth *Twas the night before Easter, when all through the chat / Not a chatter was stirring, not even a rat. / The schedule was hung by the starboard with care, / In hopes that T-800 soon would be there.*

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I wanted to do it for a weekend.

Comment: @Valorum But the comments above suggest that others don't.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - They seem to be having a problem with the date, not the day

Comment: @Valorum Well, Monica said she wouldn't be able to do the 21st/22nd weekend either, and Edlothiad wanted it before the 14th ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Mid-week didn't work out so well for us last time.

Comment: I can do midweek except Mondays! Maybe we should have a Doodle poll?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - Midweeks haven't worked out well in the past. Participation seems to be quite low

Comment: @MissMonicaE - Possibly, but how do you prevent abuse? Better, I think to simply pick a closer date.

Comment: I'll be the useless complainer who says that this seems to run counter to the spirit of a Ladies' Night theme.  :-/

Answer (score 6):

**The Terminator Movie Night was a success. We had a good number of participants (7) as well as a slightly higher number of lurkers (8).** On the downside, despite the "*Ladies Night*" motif we only had one female *active* participant and a couple of female lurkers.

MissMoniceE (who proposed the film) was unable to attend due to schedulding conflicts but will get first pick of the theme for the next Movie Night as compensation. Go pester her in chat if there's a genre you're especially interested in.

---

On a related note, the video-room (provided by Watch2Gether.com) was useful. At one point we had seven people viewing the site at the same time.

---

**Groan-worthiest comment goes to *me* for**

> **Valorum:** *I'm going to make myself a drink but*
>   ***I'LL BE BACK***

**Funniest comment goes to**

> **CandiedMango:** *"I'm pretty sure Sarah looks exactly like @steelersquirrel"*

and

> **Kyle Jones:** *Can you really get your hair like that after a shower without Expensive Hair Care Products?*

[image]

**The winner of the "Captain Obvious" award (for stating the bleeding obvious) goes to**

> **Ixrec:** *the iguana never contributes to the plot in this series*

**And a special mention to JoleneAlaska for getting overexcited**

> **Jolenealaska:** *Run sarah!*