# May Movie Night Winner: Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind - 13th May at 10pm UTC (11pm BST, 6pm EDT)

Tags: discussion, movie-night

After an exhaustive search for our preferred "Post Apocalyptic" film, we have a firm winner; [**Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)). We'll be [watching together](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/what-is-a-movie-night-really) on **Saturday 13th May at 10pm UTC** *(11pm BST, 6pm EDT)*

[image]

We will be hosting a copy in a shared video room: https://www.watch2gether.com/rooms/1gg0st8z7l4jpfj4xd

### FAQ

**Q.** What is a [movie night](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/what-is-a-movie-night-really) and how does it work?
**A.** It's like trying to push water uphill.

**Q.** How do I nominate a film?
**A.** You're [too late](http://68.media.tumblr.com/b61e2aaa80c3250a9550489c9ef03c15/tumblr_mj4eqfrhby1ruuu4oo1_500.gif).

**Q.** What if I'm a vile misogynist who *[still](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10734/april-movie-night-special-its-ladies-night?noredirect=1&lq=1)* wants to watch a film with no women?
**A.** Wait until June.

---

<s>Propose your favorite post-apocalyptic movies for us to watch! This is more about how people survive the aftermath of a [TEOTWAWKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivalism#Survivalist_terminology) event than about how they make it through the event itself, but it's okay if your movie contains some of both.</s>

### Rules.

- Nominations **must** be post-apocalyptic in nature.
- The votes will be counted and verified at **Midnight UTC on Wednesday 10th May**, to give people time to procure copies of the chosen film.

#### Extra points...

Extra points were fun on the last movie night, in my humble opinion, so here are the extra points for this one:

- +1 if the nature of the apocalypse reflects a widespread *societal angst of the time* and place the movie was made, such as [nuclear apocalypse movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_holocaust_fiction#Films) from the Cold War
- +1 if you can make a case that the nature of the apocalypse reflects a widespread *societal angst of today* in the place of your choosing, such as [runaway global warming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_change_in_popular_culture)
- +1 if the nature of the apocalypse is such that we can  (at least semi-)seriously *worry about it happening in the real world in our lifetimes*, such as [emerging infectious diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemic#In_popular_culture)

#### Other notes

Valorum has [promised](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10734/april-movie-night-special-its-ladies-night) the vile misogynists among us a chance to nominate movies with no women in them at all.

> **Q.** What if I'm a vile misogynist who wants to watch a film with no women in it at all?
>   **A.** *Wait until May.*

Try to include a source, if you have one, to feed into the [video-sharing room](https://www.watch2gether.com), but you don't have to have a source to nominate!

---

It doesn't have to be a movie, as long as it's not too much longer than feature-length. A TV mini-series or web-series is just fine too and don't forget that you can nominate more than one work if you want to.

**Don't die!**

Comment: @Randal'Thor a whole show, or a particular episode, or what? I would be fine with anything roughly feature-film-length.

Comment: I've got something with six half-hour episodes, making for a total of three hours (minus a bit if we skip credits and stuff each time). Like I suggested with *Best of Both Worlds* last time, we could either watch the whole thing, or stop at some cliffhanger to make sure people watch the rest later :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor sounds good to me!

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Movie *length* is fine, as long as it's a continuous story like a mini-series and not just several episodes of a TV show.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - I've taken the liberty of doing some edits.

Comment: _"nominations must be post-apocalyptic in nature"_ - should we wait a bit then?

Comment: When does the voting close on the nominations? And when is the movie night itself meant to be?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Erm, dunno. Let me have a think

Comment: So, are downvotes going to count for the final score this time around? I kind of agree with last time only counting upvotes, but it makes it much harder to tell who's winning.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - I think we'll count upvotes and downvotes this time around. It's hotly contested so being able to see who's winning is gonna be important

Comment: You really want that _28 Days Later_ recommendation, don't you?

Comment: Perhaps [The Quiz Broadcast](http://thatmitchellandwebb.wikia.com/wiki/The_Quiz_Broadcast), if everyone’s short on time.

Comment: ha ha ha vile misogynists, foiled again

Answer (score 14):

### [Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film))

[image: Poster]

This is a 1984 animated science fiction film directed and written by the God of Animation Hayayo Miyazaki, based on his manga of the same name. It features a post-apocalyptic future where wars have devastated the planet. I couldn't really summarise it better than the Google blurb (as I haven't watched it myself):

> Far in the future, after an apocalyptic conflict has devastated much of the world's ecosystem, the few surviving humans live in scattered semi-hospitable environments within what has become a "toxic jungle." Young Nausicaä lives in the arid Valley of the Wind and can communicate with the massive insects that populate the dangerous jungle. Under the guidance of the pensive veteran warrior, Lord Yupa, Nausicaä works to bring peace back to the ravaged planet.

The film is regarded as the start of the famous Studio Ghibli, being the first collaboration of Hayao Miyazaki and Isao Takahata.

The film features (according to various sources) themes of pacifism, environmental dangers, and looking after nature.

For those who find this important, the film has been dubbed in English, featuring voices of Alison Lohman, Patrick Stewart, Shia LaBeouf, and Uma Thurman (and if you aren't in already - Mark Hamill).

Now for the downside - **it doesn't appear to be available for streaming on *ahem* suitable websites** in suitable quality.

---

Tallying the bonus points:

- "Widespread societal angst of that time" - yes, for the theme of pacifism (1984, war, all that) - **+1**;
- "Societal angst of today" - yes, for the same reasons, and the environmental concerns - **+1**;
- "Realistic nature of the apocalypse" - yes, very much so (for the reasons above) - **+1**

**Total: +3 bonus points**.

Comment: Downvoters - I find your lack of taste disturbing.

Comment: I am not quite sure why anyone would down vote this, it was a great anime. Your take on Post Apocalyptic is different than mine as I took it to be the Beginning of the worlds population coming together. I am somewhat supprised no one came up with any of the Appleseed Anime's - Appleseed (film) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appleseed_(film)

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya I've heard about them, but don't know enough about them to nominate.

Comment: Here is a link to a stand alone Move in the series - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNDb2J6DIwg - What I know is ... well everything went to Hell in a handcart. There may be a City named Olympus that has retained Technology.

Comment: What a good theme this time. For once I find myself desiring to watch the top _3_ films, when often there's only 1 or 2 in the entire list. Time to set a reminder so I actually show up this time!

Comment: @CreationEdge Don't forget to [register](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley?tab=schedule)!

Comment: I can't remember if I bought this for $5 in the bin at Walmart, or paid more. But whatever the price, I own it, and you should, too!

Comment: @WayneWerner I have it :) Still haven't watched though. I have a feeling that more people will acquire it after this film night ;)

Answer (score 10):

I nominate a genuinely great film that hasn't gotten the attention it deserves:

## [The Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_(2009_film))

[image]

Based on the Pulitzer Prize-winning [novel of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road) by [Cormac McCarthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cormac_McCarthy), [*The Road*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-road) follows a man (Viggo Mortensent) and his son (Kodi Smit-McPhee) in their struggle to survive in a bleak, lifeless, post-apocalyptic world.

---

## Awards and Acclaim:

### For the Movie:

[image]

> Joe Morgenstern from the Wall Street Journal states that viewers have to **"hang on to yourself for dear life, resisting belief as best you can in the face of powerful acting, persuasive filmmaking and the perversely compelling certainty that nothing will turn out all right."**
>
> Esquire screened the film before it was released and called it **"the most important movie of the year"** and **"a brilliantly directed adaptation of a beloved novel, a delicate and anachronistically loving look at the immodest and brutish end of us all."**... IGN gave it four and a half out of a possible five stars, calling it **"one of the most important and moving films to come along in a long time."**
>
> Tom Huddleston from Time Out calls the film **"...as direct and unflinching an adaptation as one could reasonably hope for."** He calls it **"...certainly the bleakest and potentially the least commercial product in recent Hollywood history... a resounding triumph"**, noting its **"stunning landscape photography [which] sets the melancholy mood, and Nick Cave’s wrenching score..."**
>   -  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_(2009_film))

### For the Novel:

- 2007 Pulitzer Prize for Fiction winner
- 2006 James Tait Black Memorial Prize for Fiction winner
- 2006 Believer Book Award winner
- 2006 National Book Critics Circle Award for fiction finalist
- 2012 Best of the James Tait Black shortlist
- 2008 Entertainment Weekly "Best book, fiction or non-fiction, of the past 25 years"

---

## Bonus Point Criteria:

Although the nature of the cataclysm that destroyed the earth is never revealed, and in fact, is rarely addressed, it is based on the author's anxieties regarding the dangers his own son will face in the near future - anxieties that are shared by a large portion of the general public, and are indeed a common focus of widespread societal angst.

### The Nature of the Apocalyptic Event:

Neither the novel nor the film reveal the exact cause of the apocalypse, and McCarthy himself refuses to resolve the issue, but [readers and viewers have proposed any number of possible scenarios](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-was-the-catastrophe-that-happened-in-the-road), and McCarthy seems to find them all acceptable.  The most common theories are climate change, nuclear war, massive volcanic activity (of the kind a supervolcano, like the one in Yellowstone National Park, might unleash), or an asteroid or comet colliding with the earth.

McCarthy's comments:

> When asked recently, in a conversation with the Wall Street Journal, about the nature of the catastrophic event in The Road, [McCarthy] answered by saying: **"I don't have an opinion. It could be anything – volcanic activity or it could be nuclear war. It is not really important. The whole thing now is, what do you do? The last time the caldera in Yellowstone blew, the entire North American continent was under about a foot of ash. People who've gone diving in Yellowstone lake say that there is a bulge in the floor that is now about 100 feet high and the whole thing is just sort of pulsing. From different people, you get different answers, but it could go in another three to four thousand years or it could go on Thursday..."**
>   -  [Source](https://www.theguardian.com/theobserver/2009/dec/20/observer-profile-cormac-mccarthy)

The film's director is inclined to believe that the apocalypse was caused by the damage our species is doing to the planet:

> "It just builds on the story that we are creating of the revenge of nature...  We are certainly heightening the environmental threat."
>   -  [Source](http://articles.latimes.com/2008/aug/17/entertainment/ca-road17/3)

The specific nature of the cataclysm may be a mystery, but McCarthy *has* revealed what inspired his apocalyptic vision - his concerns about the course mankind is on, and the destructive nature of our species:

> Being a septuagenarian dad in the modern age is sobering. “When you’re young and single, you hang out in bars and don’t think about what’s going to happen,” McCarthy says. “But in the next fifty years **when you have kids, you start thinking of their life and the world they have to live in. And that’s a sobering thought these days. I’m not one of those conspiracy guys, but the world is in a very unstable situation.** If you were to take thoughtful people on, say, January 1st, 1900, and tell them what the twentieth century was going to look like, they’d say, Are you shitting me?’ ”
>
> McCarthy began to wonder about the future facing his boy. **“I think about John all the time and what the world’s going to be like,” he says. “It’s going to be a very troubled place.”** One night, during a trip to Texas with John, McCarthy imagined such a place. While his son slept, McCarthy gazed out the window of his room and pictured flames on the hill. He later decided to write a novel about it; The Road is dedicated to his son. **While McCarthy suggests that the ash-covered world in the novel is the result of a meteor hit, his money is on humans destroying each other before an environmental catastrophe sets in. “We’re going to do ourselves in first,” he says.**
>
> **In part, he blames an increasingly violent society.** “If kids are unstable, they may very well be cranked up by the violence they see, and might do things that they wouldn’t have done or would have taken them longer to get around to,” McCarthy says. “But the real culprit is violence against children. A lot of children don’t grow up well. They’re being starved and sexually molested. We know how to make serial killers. You just take a Type A kid who’s fairly bright and just beat the crap out of him day after day. That’s how it’s done.”
>   -  [Source](http://www.davidkushner.com/article/cormac-mccarthys-apocalypse/)

McCarthy is a research fellow at the Santa Fe Institute, and his work there led to a preoccupation with catastrophic events, including asteroid impacts, nuclear war, volcanic activity, and climate change:

> IT’S THE SIXTH ANNIVERSARY or September 11th, and scientists from the Santa Fe Institute are contemplating the end of the world. **The occasion is a three-day conference on climate change. This evening, no one in the standing-room crowd of locals crammed into the auditorium recognizes McCarthy as he hunkers into his seat down front.** When I remark on how many people are interested in tonight’s topic, McCarthy replies, “Of course it’s relevant – we’re all going to die.”
>
> ONE DAY A FEW YEARS AGO, after checking his mail and pouring his coffee, McCarthy gingerly made his way down the hall at the Institute. He passed the equation-scrawled windowpane, down the steps where Dr. Zen was curled in the corner, past the long, red sofa where a grad student lay sprawled, and into the corner office of his friend Doug Erwin. Then he started asking about the apocalypse. In particular, he wanted to know about extinction-the Cretaceous-Tertiary meteorite that wiped out the dinosaurs 65 million years ago.
>
> Erwin is the guy to ask. A Smithsonian paleobiologist with a boyish fop of brown hair, Erwin is an expert on the subject: He wrote a book titled Extinction. He and McCarthy share a wry and fatalistic view of our time here on Earth. “The planet is going to do just fine without us,” Erwin says. “We’re an encephalized ape that won’t last long.”
>
> **Erwin told McCarthy about the likely aftermath of the deadly meteorite: the magnitude of the desolation, the collapse of ecosystems, the fallout of debris and gases. Then, one day last year, Erwin sat down to read a galley of The Road, which depicts the harrowing, post-apocalyptic journey of a father and son. Erwin smiled – so this is what McCarthy was up to, he figured.**
>    -  [Source](http://www.davidkushner.com/article/cormac-mccarthys-apocalypse/)

### Bonus Point Score:  +3

- *Reflects a widespread societal angst of the time and place the movie was made:*  Twenty-first century earth is rife with angst regarding all the fears mentioned above.  **+1**
- *Reflects a widespread societal angst of today in the place of your choosing:*  Again, this angst is common today.  **+1**
- *We can (at least semi-)seriously worry about it happening in the real world in our lifetimes:*  Yes, we can seriously worry about nuclear war, volcanic activity, asteroid impacts, and climate change.  **+1**

***Note: There are a handful of women in the film, but few of them have any dialogue, and none are named (in fact, even the main characters are nameless in both the movie and the book - they are referred to exclusively as "the Man" and "the Boy").  I'm not saying this is a good thing - I only mention it because it was brought up in the question.***

Comment: When you refer to the author as "McCormac," is that a typo or a fan name, like J-Law?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - A typo that I KEEP MAKING!!!

Comment: Depressing as hell, this film.

Answer (score 8):

### I propose *Zombieland*.

[image: Poster]

Reasons why we should watch this:

1. **Bill F-ing Murray**

[image]

2. **Emma Stone**

[image]

3. **Ghostbusters**

[image]

Finally the fiddlybits

- "Widespread societal angst of that time" / "Societal angst of
  today"-  The main character struggles with dating, something that
  plagues many of us today. **+2**
- "Realistic nature of the apocalypse" - Zombies due to some disease.
  **+1**

**Bonus +3**

Comment: This is so ridiculous (especially the bonus points), that I have to upvote!

Comment: I just bought the BR recently, too! Not sure about the video sharing room thing, though.

Comment: Also: Widespread societal angst of that time/our time is both "Millennials feeling like their fighting against the world to find the place they fit" but here they're _literally_ fighting and the rest of us only figuratively.

Answer (score 7):

I propose

### [The Quiet Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089869/).

This film is a masterpiece of post-apocalyptica. Zac Hobson wakes up to find that he's quite literally the last man on Earth as everyone else seems to have completely vanished into thin-air. After a truly *chilling* first 10 minutes, the rest of the film is based around him (and us) trying to work out what the hell happened.

Eventually, Zac goes bonkers. Highlights of his madness include cross-dressing,  roaming the city waving a shotgun, declaring himself 'Emperor of the World' and challenging God to a duel(!).

---

This is truly a movie that'll make you ask yourself "***If I were the last man on Earth, what would I do?***"

---

**Societal Angst?** = **+1**. It would spoil the film to explain why the world's gone to crap, but suffice to say it's down to white male scientists experimenting with technology they don't understand.

Comment: So they were experimenting on women?

Comment: @Skooba - Women are indeed incomprehensible, but they aren't generally considered to be *technology*.

Comment: I think women are *magic*, and since we are on SFF, I must apply Clarke's third law...

Comment: Sheesh I should have know you had watched that, I figure I am the only one that has seen that movie but it is great.

Comment: This looks interesting and you have my +1. It also gets points from me for being from New Zealand and a few decades old. Though the pedant in me must point out that the trailer strongly suggests he's not *literally* the last man on Earth.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Spoilers!

Comment: @Randal'Thor I agree Valorm gave a good synopsis and my opinion is, this is a Cult Classic and while I think it should be for everyone, I get the feeling the Cult is smaller than it should be. He if this one wins, I am all in, It very much does deal with What the hell am I going to do now that the world is ended.

Answer (score 5):

## [*9* (2009 animated feature film by Shane Acker)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9_%282009_animated_film%29)

> Our world is ending. But life must go on.

[image]

Nine ragdolls with zips on their front and a digit painted on their back awake in a world where humanity is dead, but have left terrible war machines after themselves.

Great post-apocalyptic movie.

Do not confuse this film with the 2005 short film this is based on.

Comment: The character animations for the short film are so bad quality it's distracting.  Good thing they improved on that for the feature.

Comment: 'Tis a very touching movie, and the premise is very original.

Answer (score 5):

[**I AM LEGEND**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480249/)

> Robert Neville is a scientist who was unable to stop the spread of the
>   terrible virus that was incurable and man-made. Immune, Neville is now
>   the last human survivor in what is left of New York City and perhaps
>   the world. For three years, Neville has faithfully sent out daily
>   radio messages, desperate to find any other survivors who might be out
>   there. But he is not alone. Mutant victims of the plague -- The
>   Infected -- lurk in the shadows... watching Neville's every move...
>   waiting for him to make a fatal mistake. Perhaps mankind's last, best
>   hope, Neville is driven by only one remaining mission: to find a way
>   to reverse the effects of the virus using his own immune blood. But he
>   knows he is outnumbered... and quickly running out of time.

[image: I Am Legend]

---

BONUS POINTS:

- Social Angst **+1** -  Robert Neville is the last human survivor surrounded by mutant victims of plague.
- Real world possibility of this happening **+1** -  The plague was caused by an incurable mad-made virus.

TOTAL BONUS POINTS: **+2**

Comment: I was thinking of this one as loved the bond between Rob and his Dog so definitely a +1 from me. Then thought someone's bound to suggest it so thought I'd go classic (which is working remarkably well *cough*).

Comment: Nice nomination! Awesome movie!

Comment: I thought this was just a post apocalypse movie night, not a *bad* movie night.

Comment: @GwenKillerby Huh?  Who is putting down Will Smith here?  This isn't the place for political rants about how "icky" Charlton Heston is...this is _supposed_ to be fun suggestions for movie night, not political rants.  I have zero idea what your comment has to do with the movie that was suggested here.

Comment: @steelersquirrel - Agreed. I don't see how this comment could lead to anything other than ill-feeling

Answer (score 5):

I nominate the classic *[Threads](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090163/)* (1984), and I'm surprised it hasn't come up yet!
It's superior to, for example, *The Day After* because it shows the after effects of nuclear war much better.

[image: poster]

Comment: You can nominate more than one thing, but if you do, can you give each of them its own post? Otherwise the voting gets confused.

Comment: Also, is there an actual movie about Trump that you're proposing? If so, can you include a title and a summary, but if you're just kvetching, can you take it out? It's distracting (and rude). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Mad Max: Fury Road](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392190/)

[image: furyfury]

I watched this movie on an airplane. It was good even on such a little screen and $1 headphones that were probably worn by several other people...

But I digress... The movie is about a society in the desert where water, gas (aka petrol), and apparently women are controlled by a select few warlord type bad guys.

Something, something, dark-side... oh and there is dudes getting high on silver spray-paint.

---

Do I award my own bonus points?

- "Widespread societal angst of that time" / "Societal angst of today" +2

  That time and today are the same thing since the movie was 2015. The overtones of having clean water and actually being able to grow plants is something I hear people whine about on Facebook.
- "Realistic nature of the apocalypse"  + (over) 9,000

  because... this guy...

  [image]

Comment: I LOVE THIS MOVIE

Comment: That looks like a Health & Safety fail right there.

Comment: I probably won't upvote this as I've watched it recently, but I've heard there's a black and white version of the film out there that's supposedly the way the director prefers it. I guess if I can find that version, I could watch it in parallel.

Comment: https://i.redd.it/d1ofyqoe7zuy.jpg heres a funny

Comment: This movie is just awesome...

Answer (score 4):

### Silent Running (1972)

> In the future, all plant life on Earth has become extinct. A few specimens have been preserved in enormous, greenhouse-like geodesic domes attached to a fleet of American Airlines space freighters, currently just outside the orbit of Saturn. Freeman Lowell (Bruce Dern), one of four crewmen aboard the Valley Forge, is the resident botanist and ecologist who carefully preserves a variety of plants for their eventual return to Earth and the reforestation of the planet.
>   Orders come from Earth to jettison and destroy the domes (with nuclear
>   charges) and return the freighters to commercial service. Lowell rebels and opts
>   instead to save the plants and animals on his ship. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Running))

[image]

Pretty good movie, IMHO.  And I think the theme speaks both to the era it was made, and many of today's environmental concerns.

Comment: My concern with this film is that it's not very interactive. Long peaceful scenes of robot gardening don't really make for an interesting shared viewing experience.

Comment: @Valorum.  That's a fair point.  It's certainly not a seat-grabber like Mad Max or the like, and probably not everyone's cup of chai.  I just thought I'd mention it to add a lil' something to the discussion.  Cheers!

Comment: I suppose I'm a bit biased since I'm going to be organising the night and basically have to watch whatever wins :-)

Comment: Plus, when everyone gets choked up at the end — *<sniffle>* … But, only Freeman thinks that they are “post-apocalyptic”, so does it count?

Answer (score 3):

Let's go classic!

### [*The Day of the Triffids*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids_(1981_TV_series))

Based on John Wyndham's classic post-apocalyptic novel, this TV series is, in my opinion, a worthy adaptation of the chilling tale of carnivorous plants ravaging a world filled with blind humans. No list of post-apocalyptic stories would be complete without mentioning Wyndham's works.

As well as being a genuinely terrifying story, *The Day of the Triffids* includes commentary on social issues of the time, such as the arms race of the Cold War and its potential consequences, and how humans would react if society became much smaller and divided into the capable (those who could still see) and the less capable (the blind).

[image]
[image]

(The TV series consists of six half-hour episodes, which would make for a total run time of **3 hours**, less if we skip the credits each time. If this is too long, we could stop at a cliffhanger to keep people's interest ;-) )

---

**Bonus points**

- "the nature of the apocalypse reflects a widespread societal angst of the time and place the movie was made" - **1 point** (see above);
- "the nature of the apocalypse reflects a widespread societal angst of today in the place of your choosing" - **0.5 points** for the lengthy inspection of human society, including mob mentality, reproduction and gender issues, martial law, needs of the many versus needs of the few;
- "the nature of the apocalypse is such that we can (at least semi-)seriously worry about it happening in the real world in our lifetimes" - **0.5 points**: the blindness part is at least semi-plausible, even if the Triffids aren't.

### Total: 2 points

Comment: Plant apocalypse? I prefer _The Happening_

Comment: You get my upvote for your recommendation - I love Wyndham's novels and was brought up on the TV Series *Chocky*, which imo has the scariest theme of all children's sci fi tv shows.

Answer (score 3):

**Mad Max (1979)**

**Official Trailer:** Mad Max (1979) -

> Valorum has promised the vile misogynists among us a chance to
>   nominate movies with no women in them at all.

Is it misogynist? Oh I would say that it most certainly is

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079501/

> “Australian dystopian action film directed by George Miller, produced
>   by Byron Kennedy, and starring Mel Gibson as "Mad" Max Rockatansky,
>   Joanne Samuel, Hugh Keays-Byrne, Steve Bisley, Tim Burns, and Roger
>   Ward. James McCausland and Miller wrote the screenplay from a story by
>   Miller and Kennedy. The film presents a tale of societal collapse,
>   murder, and vengeance set in a future Australia, in which a vengeful
>   policeman becomes embroiled in a feud with a vicious motorcycle gang.
>   Principal photography took place in and around Melbourne, Australia,
>   and lasted six weeks.”

http://madmax.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_events_(original_trilogy)

> **The Persian Gulf War (Pre-Mad Max)**
>
> "Law and order, like every other aspect of the Western society have
>   been swept away - put to the torch one early morning when Iranian
>   troops trying to export revolution, struck deep into the heart of
>   Saudi Arabia". [2] The war between Iran and Saudi Arabia left the
>   Persian Gulf devastated in just two days. The oil fields were set
>   ablaze and oil export halted almost immediately. Prices of oil
>   doubled, then quadrupled and quadrupled again. North West and
>   Trans-Persian pipelines have been destroyed shortly after. The West's
>   seven biggest oil companies led by Exxon (The 7 Sisters Petroleum - as
>   seen on the tanker in Mad Max 2) have immediately announced they will
>   not fulfill their supply contracts.
>
> **Impact on Australia**
>
> The price of gold skyrocketed along with the inflation. In an attempt
>   to save the economy and conserve fuel - martial laws have been
>   announced all across the world. Italy and Spain have been taken over
>   by the military. The Australian economy collapsed, companies filed
>   bankruptcy one after another. Massive lay-offs caused the heavy
>   industry to shut down. In Sydney & Melbourne panic turned into riots.
>   People tried to withdraw savings from banks only to see the bank doors
>   nailed shut. Gas stations were sucked dry by people fighting over last
>   drops of gasoline. Ordinary citizens began to arm themselves. The
>   Outback was slowly taken over by bike gangs. The remaining oil tankers
>   were under constant attack. Vehicles that ran out of fuel were
>   abandoned on the roads. Intercity communication stopped.
>
> **Mad Max**
>
> Main Force Patrol (MFP) was formed as the last-ditch attempt to uphold
>   the law on the roads. Max Rockatansky was one of the best drivers in
>   the MFP. He went rogue after his friend and family were killed by a
>   biker gang.

**As it applies now and is it reasonable to be concerned**

The Middle East is still in turmoil and can erupt in Nuclear Explosions and of course the OIL dependency is still there. This is being aggravated by the aspects of Oil contributing to the Global Warming being experienced. The Middle East has it level of living etc based on the consumption of its Oil. Should the Non OIL Exporting countries reduce their demand then The Oil producing countries, Including Russia will have serious Financial problems.

Ergo, the perfect catch 22. IF we don’t curtail Oil Consumption can we slow down CLimate Change. IF we do curtail Oil Consumption can we CONTAIN / PERSUADE the Oil producing countries that everything will be ok :).

Comment: -1 for car chases and explosions.

Comment: Huh, the original was my least favorite Mad Max movie. I have absolutely no desire to ever watch it again, except for maybe the first ten minutes. I didn't know I was in such a minority with that opinion.

Comment: Psst @DaaaahWhoosh, For me, in that series, there is "Road Warrior" and then there are other attempts to make money that .... what ever. The First one fit the requirements more than any of the others. Besides I feel the First one is probably close to what could realistically happen than other movies that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3):

[**Planet of the Apes (Original)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063442/)

As @Rand stated...Let's go classic!

> Maniacs!! You finally blew it all up!!! God damn you all to hell!

Humanity destroys itself and apes become the dominant species.

[image: Planet of the Apes]

---

BONUS POINTS

- Social angst **+1** - I would suggest that apes taking over the world and becoming the dominant species would be considered social angst.
- Seriousness of this actually happening **+1** - Isn't the world *already* being ran by apes?

**Total points +2**

Comment: You've spoiled it now, as has the movie poster

Comment: @Valorum Hahahaha!  Sorry for spoiling it for you ;)

Comment: @GwenKillerby Good Lord!  The movie was made in 1968.  I thought that it was pretty much safe to have this movie poster, but...since it is bothering everyone so much, I will remove it.

Answer (score 3):

## [A Boy And His Dog (1975)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_and_His_Dog_(1975_film))

We all know dogs are awesome - especially so if they're telepathic, so let's gather round and chuckle at this "rather kinky tale of survival".

I'll let the trailer sell it...

> Set in a post-nuclear war of the year 2024, the main character, Vic (Don Johnson) is an 18-year-old boy, born in and scavenging throughout the wasteland of the former southwestern United States. Vic is most concerned with food and sex; having lost both of his parents, he has no formal education and does not understand ethics or morality. He is accompanied by a well-read, misanthropic, telepathic dog named Blood who helps him locate women in return for food. Blood cannot forage for himself due to the same genetic engineering that granted him telepathy. The two steal for a living, evading bands of marauders, berserk androids, and mutants. Blood and Vic have an occasionally antagonistic relationship (Blood frequently annoys Vic by calling him "Albert" for reasons never made clear), though they realize they need each other. Blood wishes to find the legendary promised land of "Over the Hill" where above ground utopias are said to exist, though Vic believes that they must make the best of what they have.

Not to mention some interesting [quotes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072730/quotes) and a rather interesting ending...

Since someone else has gone for relationships as a bonus point and there's increasing noise about nuclear weapons recently - can i haz **2 bonus points** please?

Comment: You may haz them. Nuclear armageddon is certainly a timely concern.

Answer (score 1):

### City of Ember

[image]

Comment: Hum I had totaly forgotten this movie .... it was a good movie

Answer (score 0):

### After Earth

[image]