# June Dark Fantasy Film Night - "Pan's Labyrinth" on Saturday, June the 3rd, 9pm UTC (5pm EDT, 10 pm BST)!

Tags: discussion, movie-night

Seeing that the scores seem to have settled, it's time to announce the winner - [***Pan's Labyrinth (El Laberinto Del Fauno)***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457430/), [proposed by doppelgreener](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10942/70236).

[image] [image]

> In 1944 Spain young Ofelia and her ailing mother arrive at the post of her mother's new husband, a sadistic army officer who is trying to quell a guerrilla uprising. While exploring an ancient maze, Ofelia encounters the faun Pan, who tells her that she is a legendary lost princess and must complete three dangerous tasks in order to claim immortality.

## We'll be discussing it [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) as we're watching it, and the film will be hosted by doppelgreener in [this Rabb.it room](https://www.rabb.it/pandemicsmiles). Come join us!

Meanwhile, here's the trailer:

---

### FAQ:

**Q:** What is a film night?
**A:** [Read here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/what-is-a-movie-night-really).

**Q:** How do I attend?
**A:** Register [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe?tab=schedule), and monitor this question for updates.

**Q:** Do I have to bring my own copy?
**A:** Most probably not.

Comment: I'm also looking for a third category for which t oaward a bonus point - any input is appreciated ;)

Comment: I would consider SuckerPunch dark by your above considerations. Theres a bunch of female protagonists right there.

Comment: Another female protag one is Pan's Labryinth.

Comment: How are you guys not doing a special movie night for May 25th?

Comment: @phantom42 National Tap Dance Day? Ah, the [geek pride day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek_Pride_Day). Never heard about it before.

Comment: Really? It's the 40th anniversary of *Star Wars* being released.

Comment: Maleficent also has a female protagonist.

Comment: @Gnemlock Sheesh I like "Sucker Punch" but bring it up and I get nothing but blowback on it.

Comment: @phantom42 Didn't know about that one :)

Comment: @MissMonicaE Please, do nominate ;)

Comment: @MissMonicaE I think that is a very good movie was well and certainly worth nominating.

Comment: Would _The Cabin in the Woods_ qualify?  Or is it a bit much for these such gatherings?

Comment: Although:  I am rather sore that I can't nominate a radio drama here, and so I'll probably abstain like I've done for every other such _Movie_ Night.

Comment: @can-ned_food Looks like it's too much mystery and not enough fantasy.

Comment: @can-ned_food If you did, you wouldn't get any push-back from me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Pan's Labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%27s_Labyrinth)

[image]

This is a Mexican-Spanish film **(non-hollywood)**. A young girl, Ofelia, is in difficult straits — she's growing up in the middle of a war, her family's in difficulty, and her mother is ailing. Ofelia meets some extremely weird, freakish, and wonderful creatures — including the faun above who you may have seen before. The faun believes her to be the reincarnation of a powerful figure, and sets her off into fantastic and perilous circumstances.

It was written and directed by [Guillermo del Toro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillermo_del_Toro). It has extremely high ratings on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457430/) (8.2/10), [Metacritic](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457430/criticreviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt) (98/100), and [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/pans_labyrinth/) (95% critics, 91% audience). Those scores are all very well deserved.

It's one of my favorite films that I've been meaning to re-watch, and I'd be happy to watch it with all of you should this one get chosen.

This film has **English subtitles** but not an English dub. (Gallifreyan has found there's a Russian dub, but I can't vouch for its quality.)

---

**Bonus points**:

- Foreign film - yes. **+1**
- Female protagonist - yes. **+1**
- Available for video room - no.

### +2 total

Comment: My wife and I enjoyed this movie a lot and probably would give it the same kind of rating as IMDB did.

Comment: @Gallifreyan re "available for video room", I see it's [available for rent on Youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8QN6.png). To what extent does that count? (Does it not?)

Comment: Not sure. It has to work in the [shared video room](https://www.watch2gether.com/?lang=en)

Comment: I guess if you pay the £2.49 for everyone to watch it?

Comment: I just tried and I can't even access the YouTube Movies page.

Comment: Like David Bowie's Labrynth meets The Boy in The Striped Pyjamas

Comment: @Gallifreyan Closer to the movie night date in June I'll try out a free trial of Watch2gether and see if it will let me 'cast the rented copy from Youtube.

Comment: @doppelgreener You can try rabb.it for that - I don't think Watch2Gether Pro supports anything that is not available publicly. With Rabbit you can stream it directly.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Yes, but that would be very not cool. Sharing a publicly available video is one thing,  streaming it for an audience is another.

Comment: @Valorum Even if for friends?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Even for friends :-)

Comment: @Toby That is an impressive analogy and it works. :D

Answer (score 14):

### [Constantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_(film))

[image: Poster] [image: Poster]

This 2005 film is [loosely based](http://www.tor.com/2015/11/12/constantine-is-a-terrible-hellblazer-adaption-but-a-damned-good-modern-noir/) on [vertigo-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertigo-comics)'s *Hellblazer* comic series, which is the very *definition* of the dark fantasy genre.

John Constantine is an "occult detective" - a person who deals with certain problems of supernatural sort.

Here's a summary [from Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/constantine/):

> An ordinary man with an extraordinary gift must save the planet from evil in this action-packed fantasy. Unknown to most people, the world is crowded with spirits both good and evil who walk among us in human guise. One of the few who can see these spirits is John Constantine, but the responsibility of his vision is more than he can stand, and he tries to kill himself. Saved from death, Constantine must now atone for his actions by acting as a guardian in the middle ground between Paradise and Hell. Constantine also makes the acquaintance of Angela Dodson, a police detective who becomes aware of his unusual gift while looking into the death of her sister; he leads her into the unknown world of the spirits and soon circumstances demand that they join forces in a desperate bid to save humanity from evil.

**Pros**:

- Keanu Reeves' charm (and great acting, by the way)

  [image]
- Tilda Swinton playing the archangel Gabriel (and **nails** it)

  [image]

  > You are going to die young because you smoked 30 cigarettes a day since you were 15... and you're going to go to Hell because of the life you took. You're fucked.
- An absolutely charming portrayal of Lucifer

  [image]
- A solid performance by Rachel Weisz

  [image]
- Not one gorram kiss or display of affection

**Cons**:

- R rated, for some very brief nudity (it's not actually nudity, but still), some violence, and demonic images
- Also this ridiculous thing:

  [image]
  <sub>Luckily, it only appears briefly.</sub>

---

**Bonus points**:

- Foreign film - no.
- Female protagonist - no.
- Available for video room - no.

Comment: Peter Stormare: For whenever Hollywood needs a threatening, vaguely Russian guy type character.

Comment: @Toby It took your comment for me to realise he's playing Czernobog in _American Gods_ - I didn't recognise him without the beard! 0_o

Comment: And a good job he's making of it too so far! Considering he is so often typecast he always makes each role its own - very talented IMO (especially considering he's Swedish, not Russian, LOL)

Comment: @Toby I like him - may be a bit too stereotypical with the accent, but I guess this the one instance when stereotypes are not appropriate but needed. By the way, we have a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57003/american-gods-the-god-of-spoilers) with spoilers from _American Gods_ book and TV series.

Comment: "Ridiculous thing" _where can I buy one_

Comment: And … One year later:  To be the “very _definition_”, shouldn't it be the first to be defined as such?  Maybe _epitome_ is better choice of word.

Answer (score 9):

#### Online copy not available for streaming in the shared video room

---

### [Coraline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coraline_%28film%29)

This is a 2009 stop-motion animated film, based on Neil Gaiman's novella of the same name.

A summary of the novel from [Neil Gaiman's website](http://www.neilgaiman.com/works/Books/Coraline/):

> When Coraline steps through a door to find another house strangely similar to her own (only better), things seem marvelous.
>
> But there's another mother there, and another father, and they want her to stay and be their little girl. They want to change her and never let her go.
>
> Coraline will have to fight with all her wits and courage if she is to save herself and return to her ordinary life.

And a summary of the film from [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/coraline/):

> Coraline Jones is a girl of 11 who is feisty, curious, and adventurous beyond her years. She and her parents have just relocated from Michigan to Oregon. Missing her friends and finding her parents to be distracted by their work, Coraline tries to find some excitement in her new environment. Coraline seriously doubts that her new home can provide anything truly intriguing to her, but it does; she uncovers a secret door in the house. Walking through the door and then venturing through an eerie passageway, she discovers an alternate version of her life and existence.

This is a beautiful film, suitable both for (older) children and adults. It's available on [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/title/70105599) - but not so much on other venues.

While it is based on a children's novel, the atmosphere is not at all lighthearted, and it will provide entertainment even to adult audience.

---

**Bonus points:**

- Foreign film - no.
- Female protagonist - yes. **+1**
- Available for video room - no.

### +1 total

Comment: I think *Coraline* is a wonderful movie, for all ages. Scottie dogs for the win! +1

Comment: I personally can't stand to watch pretty much anything Tim Burton and this is one of the worst. I'll see if I can come up with an alternative.

Comment: @CreationEdge But... This isn't a Tim Burton film...

Comment: @Gallifreyan Might as well be, though. Dark Circles Under the Eyes: ✔️, Creepy Faces: ✔️, Monsters/Creepy Authority: ✔️.  The list goes on. Very Tim Burton-like, so pretend I said that. (Not to mention the same guy made TNBC).

Comment: Haha, and you know what, I just realized there is _one_ Tim Burton movie I like, and it's in this category, _and_ it's included on Prime Video _and_ it's on my upcoming watchlist. \*insert foot in mouth\*

Comment: Great Movie, excellent choice, was one of 4 I had selected, Corpse Bride is another .... waiting to see if some one else post that, if not I may go ahead and add it.

Comment: *Coraline* is great. I just hope something more obscure wins (*Constantine* may not count either). ;)

Comment: @Adamant _Angel's Egg_ (below) is a good candidate for obscure, and comes both with dubbing and subs.

Answer (score 8):

## Not competing because there's no copy online :(

### [*Imaginaerum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginaerum_(film))

[image]

*Imaginaerum* is a 2012 fantasy musical film produced by the band Nightwish. While this may not sound like much, the final product is terrific - heartwarming tale of parenting, art, and many other things, equipped with beautiful scenery and a great soundtrack based on Nightwish's album of the same name.

A short summary:

> A coma sends an old man into his childhood's sinister fantasy world, where he must fight dementia and gain back his memories before it's too late.

The fantasy sequences occur in this man's head, while in the waking world his daughter is trying to piece together the unfinished song he left.

Pros:

- Surreal, obscure, and truly beautifully made

  [image]
- Surely dark enough - look at this guy:

  [image]
- A truly foreign film - a valuable contribution to the film nights' diversity

Answer (score 7):

### [*Angel's Egg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel%27s_Egg) (*Tenshi no Tamago*)

[image]

*Angel's Egg* is a 1985 Japanese animation film directed by Mamoru Oshii and written Yoshitaka Amano; the former also directed two *Ghost in the Shell* anime adaptations, and the latter illustrated Neil Gaiman's *The Sandman: Dream Hunters*:

[image]

The [premise of the film](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/tenshi_no_tamago_angels_eggegg_of_god) is as follows:

> An unnamed young girl, carrying a large egg, wanders about a surreal, nightmarish post-apocalyptic world collecting water in glass bottles. A man (also nameless),carrying a cross over his shoulder, crosses her path, and begins to follow her around during her daily routine. Despite her worries for her beloved egg (the contents of which she refuses to tell him), she eventually grows to trust him,even though his intentions remain mysterious.

The film has been widely described as ambiguous and even tripping, while also being described as an "overlooked masterpiece". The films features little dialogue, which is convenient for us, as is the fact that it's available online in various forms.

---

**Bonus points**:

- Foreign film - yes. **+1**
- Female protagonist - yes. **+1**
- Available for video room - yes **+1**

### +3 total

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know Yoshitaka Amano was also the illustrator for most of the Final Fantasy games, and worked on Speed Racer, among other animations.

Comment: I don't care what you guys watch — I'll be seeing this as soon as I get my hands on a good quality copy.

Answer (score 5):

**Big Trouble** in Little China (1986) - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090728/

**Storyline**

> Truck driver Jack Burton arrives in Chinatown, San
>   Francisco, and goes to the airport with his Chinese friend Wang Chi to
>   welcome his green-eyed fiancée Miao Yin who is arriving from China.
>   However she is kidnapped on the arrival by a Chinese street gang and
>   Jack and Wang chase the group. Soon they learn that the powerful evil
>   sorcerer called David Lo Pan, who has been cursed more than two
>   thousand years ago to exist without physical body, needs to marry a
>   woman with green eyes to retrieve his physical body and Miao is the
>   chosen one. Jack and Wang team-up with the lawyer Gracie Law, the bus
>   driver and sorcerer apprentice Egg Shen and their friends and embark
>   in a great adventure in the underground of Chinatown, where they face
>   a world of magicians and magic, monsters and martial arts fighters.

**Big Trouble In Little China Trailer HD**

Answer (score 5):

**The Brothers Grimm (2005)** - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0355295/

**Director**: Terry Gilliam

**Writer**: Ehren Kruger

**Stars**: Matt Damon, Heath Ledger, Monica Bellucci

**The Brothers Grimm - Trailer**

> In 1811, in a French occupied Germany, the crooks Brothers Grimm
>   pretend to fight against evil witches and monsters to make money.
>   However, they are arrested by Cavaldi and General Delatombe, but they
>   have a chance to redeem themselves in the village of Marbaden, where
>   ten young girls have vanished. Will and Jacob are guided by the local
>   Angelika through an enchanted forest where they face the evil Mirror
>   Queen that depends on the sacrifice of twelve girls in the eclipse to
>   stay beautiful and young.

Comment: +1 for Gilliam and Damon

Comment: This is a really good, really underrated movie.

Answer (score 2):

**Jennifer's Body (2009)** - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1131734/

**Jennifer's Body Official Trailer**

**Director**: Karyn Kusama
**Writer**: Diablo Cody
**Stars**: Megan Fox, Amanda Seyfried

> Nerdy, reserved bookworm Needy Lesnicki, and arrogant, conceited
>   cheerleader Jennifer Check are best friends, though they share little
>   in common. They share even less in common when Jennifer mysteriously
>   gains an appetite for human blood after a disastrous fire at a local
>   bar. As Needy's male classmates are steadily killed in gruesome
>   attacks, the young girl must uncover the truth behind her friend's
>   transformation and find a way to stop the bloodthirsty rampage before
>   it reaches her own boyfriend Chip

**Rated R for sexuality, bloody violence, language and brief drug use**

My memory of this movie is the R rating is far more thematic than anything else.

In my opinion, the Movie despite what one may think, really is good story telling and in my opinion, this is probably the only movie I thought that Megan's acting brought the character to life.

Comment: Given the sensibilities of certain users and moderators I would strongly suggest avoiding anything with female nudity.

Comment: It doesn't actually depict nudity though, just _hints_ at nudity. Megan Fox is [famous for refusing nude scenes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/8866/44222).

Comment: @Gallifreyan - It's your funeral. Just remember that a few days earlier it was *my* funeral.

Comment: @Valorum It'll be fiiiine, you wait and see ;)

Comment: I have not seen this movie before.  I agree with @Valorum, though.  It would seem somewhat hypocritical to screen a rated "R" movie including sexuality and language, which is obviously something that cannot be discussed in the chat room without dire consequences.

Comment: @steelersquirrel *Shrug* as I tried to say, the R rating is more about the Theme of Demonic Possesion, mayhem, conflict between best friends. The Sexuality is there, brought on by Megan Fox, but then again if she is in a Movie doesn't that instantly cast it as "Sexuality"? In this case the sexuality tends to be 100% in line with the character being played. As in not being gratuitous. As Gallifreyan has said there is no nudity, the movie relies, in that area, on a Hitchcock assertion, leave it to the imagination of the viewer, they are far better equipped than I am.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya Sure.  I was just going by the Rated R disclaimer.  I'm not opposed to movies like this at all and I'm certainly not opposed to discussing certain themes in movies such as sexuality or language.  I was just making a general statement towards being able to discuss these things in chat after what happened if the new chat room is supposed to be keeping things on a PG type of level so that nobody else is offended :)

Comment: @steelersquirrel I understand, my reply probably came off differently than I meant it. In my own way I keep trying to say the movie(visual, story telling) and the acting is far better and out weigh the visual tid bits in trailers. I am a little gun shy with things like this. When Demi Moore and forgot his name, movie "About Last Night" came out We went to see it. We thought it was a very good movie. I suggested others see it and the next day was accused of promoting Pornography because of the Bathtub scene. So yea .....

Comment: Good story, but I don't think it is quite in the style of “dark fantasy”.  IMHO.

Comment: @can-ned_food Hum, since when are Demons not considered Fantasy? And when a Demon goes on a killing spree that is not a Dark Fantasy? But thanks for your view point.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya  Haha!  Depends on who you ask!  But, anyways, although the Horror genre does overlap quite a bit with dark–fantasy classifications, I always thought that the emphasis on vulnerability and shock–horror in most scenes rather detracts from settling it as broader dark fantasy camp.

Comment: Then again, who am I to support tight and constrictive story classes?  I guess, from the demon's position, this would be dark fantasy.

Comment: @can-ned_food Indeed who is to say :) I put 3 different candidates up scaling from what I thought was lighter to darker. This one was the darker of the 3. I had reservations on the nomination, but chose to go with this because, I don't care much for Megan but this movie indicates it is not her or her acting so much as it is her being cast for certain role types.  *Shrug* this movie may have been able to show that she is also an actress, to those that see her a certain way.