# TNG TV Night ("The Inner Light") Recap

Tags: discussion, movie-night

Yesterday's TNG <s>Movie</s> TV event in the Mos Eisley chatroom was our **single most successful event** (<sup><sub>*yet*</sub></sup>), even more popular than [The Force Awakens](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/there-has-been-an-awakening-another-movie-night-force-awakens-on-monday-the-1) and with more chatters than [Alien](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/august-movie-event-2). In total we had no less than [13 active participants](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198/2017/4/29/22-23) and a further 12 lurkers, bringing the grand total to 25!

We were all having so much fun that after watching 'The Inner Light', the audience cried "*more!*" so we put the #2 choice on as well, and watched 'Best of Both Worlds, Parts I and II' until the wee small hours.

The Watch2Gether room had a few snags, but overall it proved to be real asset to the evening, allowing casual visitors to watch all three episodes without having to find their own copies.

---

'***Funniest comment***' awards go to

**Himarm's cat** for

> *reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee5tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt‌​ttttttttttttttttttttt444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444‌​444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444‌​44
>   CAT*

and

**Jolenealaska** for

> *Someone is chopping onions!*

[image]

---

The '***Captain Obvious***' award (for stating the bloody obvious) goes to **Bellatrix** for

> *Oh my gosh, Picard is a Borg now?!?*

[image]

---

A special '***Cowardy-Custard***' award goes to **zabeus** (on seeing the Borg for the first time)

> *abandon ship*

[image]

and on seeing them for the second time

> *run away*

[image]

Comment: Hey, I got an award!

Comment: @Bellatrix Captain Picard and his Borg sister, Captain Obvious.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ha ha! :) I was definitely surprised by that. Plus, I thought that was where we were ending it.

Comment: @Bellatrix - But then the crowd cried "[More, more, more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlJGrIyt-X8)"

Comment: [More!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6fmEe5N2lc) [More!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlGANfDOeSE) [More!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idAXDFt2wLU)

Comment: @Bellatrix: you guys really should have stopped there and [waited three months](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) to watch part 2, 1990-style.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I think Bellatrix would have cried. She was quite shocked by the cliffhanger.