# October Movie Night - Galaxy Quest - 2017-10-06 11:00 PM GMT / 12:00 PM BST

Tags: discussion, movie-night, chat-event

### Update: The Winning Picture is *Galaxy Quest*.

### Date: October 6, 2017  11:00 PM GMT

<s>**Do you have a favourite movie? It's time to drag it through the dirt.**</s>

For this movie night, parodies of any fantasy or science fiction movie or book should be nominated.

### Rules:

1. The parody **must be an official movie**, so no fan parodies or home videos.
2. The parody **must be intended as parody,** so really really bad sequels do not count as parodies of the original work.
3. The parody **must be about fantasy or science fiction**.

Please also explain what work is being ridiculed by your proposed parody. If multiple works are being ridiculed, it's up to you to chose one of them and explain why.

### Scoring:

Only upvotes will be counted.

- +1 bonus point for **every 1k questions** a **tag of the ridiculed work has** on the main site.
- +1 bonus point if **you** (the nominator) **have a gold badge in the tag** of the ridiculed work (I'm assuming it really *is* your favourite movie being ridiculed then).

### The winning picture will be determined on September 24th

---

### Clarification

- If **multiple tags apply** (e.g. with Tolkiens, book or movies?), **pick the one you prefer**.
- **You can co-host nominations** to get the +1 for the gold badge.

Is everything clarified now? Then [get on with it!](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l1YmS_VDvMY)

---

### FAQ

- **What is a movie night?** - [Here you go](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7434/80374).
- **Can I nominate a movie?** - Sure, just post an answer to this thread.
- **What if I can't stand that my favourite movie is being ridiculed?** - You may wanna skip this event then....

Comment: Hah! Sounds fun. I wonder if there are many parodies like this though...

Comment: https://www.geek.com/culture/the-funniest-sci-fi-parodies-of-all-time-1658036/

Comment: @Gallifreyan Spaceballs and MP and the Holy Grail came into my mind immediately.

Comment: Pity we cant watch the star wars or terminator movies in [Goblin's parody-translation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Storm_in_the_Glass)

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0 Well, you can propose it. I doubt that most of us speak Russian fluently though

Comment: *Young Frankenstein* of course. The various Seltzer and Seizburg (you know, the *Scary Movie* people) films could work, particularly *Epic Movie* and *Superhero Movie*. Then, there's always *Flesh Gordon*...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Go ahead and suggest them all :P. I might propose Spaceballs. King Kong doesn't have 1k questions yet, does it? And neither any martial arts tag

Comment: I changed the date format to avoid confusing americans

Comment: @Skooba Thanks, I always forget that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Galaxy Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Quest)

[image]

+3 bonus points for ~3.7k [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) questions.

Is it a parody or a sci-fi comedy in its own right? This movie is so awesome it is hard to tell!

> Galaxy Quest is an acknowledged homage to Star Trek; therefore a variety of elements in the former correspond to those of the latter. The television program within the film, Galaxy Quest, is set around the starship NSEA Protector, an instrument of the National Space Exploration Administration, which are parodies of the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701) and Starfleet respectively. The prefix of the Protector’s registration number NTE-3120 ostensibly alludes to some sort of similar space federation, but in reality stands for "Not The Enterprise", according to visual effects co-supervisor Bill George in a 2000 interview with Cinefex magazine.[20]
>
> This homage also extended to the original marketing of the movie, including a promotional website[21] intentionally designed to look like a poorly constructed fan website, with "screen captures" and poor HTML coding. The homage even parodied the effect that Star Trek had on the social lives of its cast members, such as how Alex Dane (played by Alan Rickman) has been typecast after his success in the Galaxy Quest television show; this reflects the lamentations of Leonard Nimoy, who had been typecast after his performance as Spock.

Comment: Upvoted just for Alan Rickman. I'd say it qualifies as a parody, or comedic value. Go and get the bonus points for Star Trek ;)

Comment: :) And you've got to love a parody that none other than William Shatner has proclaimed more a documentary.

Comment: [Consider yourself summoned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40430130#40430130) :P. If you find the time, maybe we can start another movie night for October.

Comment: @Narusan - You might consider posting a new meta with a quick roundup. I'd be happy to offer some constructive criticism

Comment: @Narusan - After the previous movie nights I tended to do a roundup to let the community know how it had gone, what lessons I'd learned about running them and my ideas for improving; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10874/tng-tv-night-the-inner-light-recap, for example.

Comment: @Narusan - If I were you, I'd be pretty pissed off about 13 people upvoting the film and then not showing up

Answer (score 11):

### [Spaceballs](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/), +4 bonus points ([star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars))

> Planet Spaceballs' President Skroob sends Lord Dark Helmet to steal planet Druidia's abundant supply of air to replenish their own, and only Lone Starr can stop them.

[image: Cover]

Sounds familiar? That's because it's a hilariously done Star Wars and Star Trek parody, doing more than fair justice to the original. All your favourite characters are in there, as well as a good deal about passwords (don't use 123456789) and hyper-space-travelling (don't use *ludicrous speed*) and even a few 4th wall break I'm not going to spoil here.

With a rating of 7.1/10 on IMDb, it comes even close to the original which holds a score of 8.7/10.

Answer (score 8):

[I'm going to assume that pastiches are also valid](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SatireParodyPastiche) and nominate *[Kung Fury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fury)*, a pastiche of cheesy 80s films involving time travel and martial arts.

[image: Kung Fury - movie poster]

> Sometime in the early 1980s, Miami-Dade Police Department detective Kung Fury and his partner Dragon apprehend a red ninja in a back alley, but Dragon is sliced in half by the ninja while Kung Fury is suddenly struck by lightning and bitten by a cobra, giving him extraordinary kung fu powers that enable him to defeat his foe. Years later in 1985, after defeating a rogue arcade machine robot, Kung Fury quits the force when he is assigned to partner with Triceracop, fearing that he would lose another partner in the line of duty. Meanwhile, Adolf Hitler, a.k.a. "Kung Führer", enters the timeline and remotely guns down the police chief and attacks the precinct through a mobile phone. Intent to avenge the chief, Kung Fury has computer whiz Hackerman send him back in time to kill Hitler in Nazi Germany. A glitch in the system, however, sends him back into the Viking Age. After Kung Fury meets the Viking valkyries Barbarianna and Katana, the Norse god Thor sends him to Nazi Germany for him to finish his job.

As a bonus, the movie is free to download, so it's very accessible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Skeleton_of_Cadavra would probably be my second suggestion. :-D

Comment: Of course they are valid.

Comment: also it is pretty short, so that makes it more accessible as the time investment is not as great as full length film.

Comment: It also streams on Netflix

Comment: +1 for the scene where someone is flung into the sky and hits the Hubble Space Telescope several years before it was launched

Answer (score 8):

### [What We Do in the Shadows](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3416742/)

**Bonus points**: 0
**Parodies:** Vampire genre
**Official**: Yes
**Main site tag**: [vampire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire)

---

Written and directed by our good mates [Taika Waititi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taika_Waititi) (*Thor: Ragnarok*) and [Jemaine Clement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jemaine_Clement) (Flight of the Conchords), *What We Do in the Shadows* is a 'mockumentary' about Vampires (and Werewolves) and their daily lives.

[image]
<sup>[img src](http://cdn.bloody-disgusting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/what-we-do-in-the-shadows.jpg)</sup>

---

Honestly, even if this doesn't get chosen, do yourselves a favour and watch it at some point!

Comment: I saw this recently- it's a fairly decent film

Answer (score 2):

## [Fanboys](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489049/) (+4 bonus [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars))

[image: Fanboys poster]

- **[View trailer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489049/videoplayer/vi3468690201?ref_=tt_pv_vi_aiv_2)**

**Parody of:** Scifi fandom in general, and Star Wars fandom more specifically. There are significant parodies of and references to scenes from Star Wars, as well as Star Trek and [other sci-fi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489049/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn).

**Premise:** You and your similarly geeky friends are die-hard Star Wars fans, and finally, after a couple decades, actual new movies are being made. You can't wait for Episode I to finally arrive. But then, one of your friends finds out that he has a terminal illness, and likely won't live to actually see the premiere of the exciting new movie he's been waiting for his whole life. Thus, a plan is hatched to take a big road trip and sneak into Skywalker Ranch so they can see the final cut of the film while their friend is still around to enjoy it. As they go on their trip, they meet an extensive cast of cameo appearances, primarily from Star Wars but also other sci-fi properties.

**Rating:** "PG-13 for pervasive crude and sexual material, language and drug content." I personally find the crude material districts from the fun of the main premise, and I even fast-forwarded through some of it that I just didn't find appealing. But even with that, it seemed that it ought to be nominated as it's a fandom film that I suspect isn't as seen as some of the more well-known ones listed here.

Answer (score -1):

**Traumschiff Surprise – Periode 1** - +3 Bonus points for 3,662 ''Star Trek'' questions.

[image: Traumschiff Surprise – Periode 1 - movie poster]

What the heck, I'll suggest one that I haven't seen myself, but is apparently fairly well regarded, *[Traumschiff Surprise – Periode 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traumschiff_Surprise_%E2%80%93_Periode_1)*. It's available on 
YouTube (although I'm now having trouble locating the version with English subtitles). It's [been cited as an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146309/23243) to a `story-identification` question (not accepted, but I still think it's the best match). And it's one of the only movies with a flying couch as a time machine.

According to Wikipedia:

> (T)Raumschiff Surprise parodies the (mostly science fiction) films Star Trek, Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace, The Fifth Element, Back to the Future, The Time Machine, Independence Day, A Knight's Tale, Men in Black, Minority Report, High Noon, The Matrix, E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial, and Twelve Monkeys.

Comment: Are you German by any chance? I wasn't even aware that English versions do exist...

Comment: @Narusan: I used to have a link to a version with English subtitles, although I'm having more difficulty finding that now.

Comment: I can only co-sponsor the movie. I have seen it, and it's hilarious (for a German audience)

Comment: I saw this at a tenth birthday party in German and didn't get any of the jokes, which might have meant "too German" or "too dirty" or a combination.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Too German probably. The jokes aren't dirty, as far as I'm aware. Might not be best suited then.

Comment: @Narusan Well, I only meant "too dirty for me to get them when I was nine," which is a pretty low bar.